# Can we get a [block] or [ignore] feature so we never have to see someone's posts again?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users)

I'm not really sure the details on how this would work, except to make the person disappear as though they never existed (so remove all their comments, questions, and answers).

It might make some comments seem out of place, but oh man, would it make time on SO more wonderful if you could magically make someone disappear.  It would also remove the impetus for people to mete out their downvoting justice to people who've annoyed them (but haven't really broken any "rules").

Comment: This is your way of saying our date didn't go well isn't it?

Comment: Related: [Ignore Users Script.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/) and [Add the ability to ignore users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/). Do note what [Marc Gravell says there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users/3410#3410).

Answer (score 7):

Cost: A lot of code editing  to show or not show a user throughout the system.
Reward: ....?

Honestly, I just don't see any benefits to justify having to build this into the system.

Comment: Reward = Tranquility. I for one would feel considerably happier with my time on SO if I could mute just one or two people. Sometimes ignorance really is bliss.

Answer (score 5):

Against this.

I don't know whos annoying you or why but you need to stop taking it seriously. Frankly, most of the time I don't even look whos really asking, answering or commenting. I'm more interested in the content than whoever is behind it. This sort of proposal while being non-trivial to implement sets a bad precedent imho.

Answer (score 5):

Another reason against this: You could easily post identical content to someone you block, leading to duplicate/redundant posts..

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a good idea... and I don't think anything will get implemented here.

However: occasionally, people change screen names. And sometimes, it gets out of hand.

I'm currently keeping tabs on one user who has used at least 5 names with about 10 edits (i.e. swapping between names); this might make it hard to ignore them by eye alone.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be difficult because you also need to consider edits.  Today edit authors are currently credited in both the history and inline in the post.  What should show up in that case for a blocked user?

I can definitely see support for this type of feature though.  It's like the equivalent of a killfile for NNTP.