# Add the ability to ignore users

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, users, abuse

Stack Overflow has successfully borrowed at least one XBox feature (Achievements).  I'd like to see another feature borrowed as well.

Let's say I'm playing Halo online and another player is being a bigot.  I have the option to add him to a list of ignored users.  After doing that, all the racist things he says will never be heard through my headphones anymore.

Now, on Stack Overflow, I'd like the ability to add a user to a list of ignored users.  This would hide all of that user's comments, and maybe his questions and answers as well (not sure if hiding questions/answers is necessary).

This serves multiple purposes:

1. It would make it easy for users to avoid other users' flamebait.
2. It would give users a more appropriate response to flamebait.
3. The ability to start flame wars would be reduced, since fewer users would see those comments.
4. Users would now have an incentive to be more diplomatic, as there is now a negative consequence to the behavior (the silent treatment).
5. Administrators could review which users are the most often ignored, which would be a strong indication that someone should be [put in the penalty box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) or even locked out of their account.
6. **Administrators wouldn't have to spend as much time dealing with complaints about abusive users, since users would have a better way to respond.**

---

[annakata](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13018/annakata) makes a good point in a comment to an answer, that I thought should get more visibility:

> I had a problem, reported it and got the response "not bad enough to do anything about, sorry". Which is kind of true, because the only options available to the mods are the nuclear one (penalty box) and the zero-effect one (do nothing). We need a middle ground option where abuse can be handled for *you* without also being handled for *everyone*.

Comment: Sorry Kip, I'm with ya, but let's keep this feature suggestion in the abstract

Comment: This would be my #1 feature request by a long mile

Comment: @kyle: it was an accidental edit collision, i promise!  you're right, the original text was probably a little hypocritical in that it was complaining about "comments engineered to incite flame wars". :(

Comment: Comment to #6. Don't we WANT the moderators to focus attention on this? This is sort of like vigilantism, except you're only helping yourself, and you're not going to the proper authorities.

Comment: @devinb maybe i'm wrong and they do want to be bothered by this kind of stuff all the time.  i don't know.  if i was an moderator, i'd want users to have more options to resolve these things themselves.

Comment: "who constantly have to intervene to resolve petty conflicts" - I'll reserve judgement on that; personally, I find the calls to blacklist users far more distracting....

Comment: There's also one about edit protection as well, which is kind of like this one.

Comment: I agree with Marc. All the talk about ignoring users or attempting to ostracize users via these posts is getting really tiresome. If you have complaints, voice them to the proper authorities and let those in charge make the decision if something needs to be done about it.

Comment: And for the record, I think the edit (r2) is a very good one, taking away most of the flamebait.

Comment: @TXI: to be fair, though, he was talking about lightening the mods' load. If the mods don't think they need their workload is that great, then it might not apply. But well said, otherwise. 

I have (facetiously) proposed that SO be run like a MUD, we earn weapons and spells to win edit duals and temporary "wards" against our "foes".... 'cause it almost sounds like life or death the way some people sound.

Comment: +1 from me too. I suggested such a feature back when we used UserVoice (http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general/suggestions/69272-implement-a-twit-filter-), but it was turned down. I hope they will implement it.

Comment: Pretty please can we get this feature.. if you add the ability that once I put them on ignore they cannot upvote downvote etc anything I do.  ...with sugar on top?

Comment: @Locutus So, instead of an "ignore" feature, you want to have the power to literally remove someone else from the site?

Comment: I request this feature.  If I ever felt bad about ignoring someone, I could click 'unignore'.  Why should users with high reputations be able to abuse me and go unpunished?  I know if I go toe-to-toe with these users, I'll likely get banned, so I'd rather ignore them like any sensible person would.  Instead, I have to let them ream me, and whoever the sadistic programmers behind this site are, they must like it.  I absolutely hate it when sites don't let you ignore users.  Even if they have something to contribute, I'd sooner see them banned for their abusive language.

Comment: Also, from a psychological perspective, control = happiness.

Comment: This is the most extreme example of closed-mindedness that I can possibly imagine. It also pushes SO in *completely* the wrong direction, to a site focused on *users* and social interaction, rather than one based on questions and answers. I'm very much opposed, and not in the way that "I would never use this", but in the way that "I think this is actively harmful for the site". If there is a problem, **we want you to point it out to the moderators**. If it's not worth pointing out, then you're obviously being over-sensitive and need to grow up a bit. Don't improve the site only for *yourself*.

Comment: Take a sample from any real life society, and you're going to find personality disorders.  How are people supposed to deal with those?  This site is crawling with losers who stalk and harass people, and there's no way to deal with it because there was little thought put into the administration pipeline.  If you report someone for annoying you, that person can get together with his 'social network' and harass you by closing all of your questions.  You want to talk about closed mindedness, how about racists?  I guess people should just change their skin tone?  Cody's solution: blame the victim.

Comment: Developing user interaction means asking people to agree to a code of conduct and then actually administrating to cause people to adhere to that code.  You can lease people the option to not agree to the code of conduct, but they should still be punished if they don't adhere to the rules.  SO permanently bans users from performing actions on the basis of bullying from established peers, which effectively adds them to every other user's ignore list.  So it's far more anti-social to not allow bans.

Comment: +1 from me. Someone (with around 9k rep, who should know better) was rude to me, because he felt I've misunderstood their very poorly written regex question ("What part of optional is not clear?"), after failing to respond to my clarification questions, and even after I had clearly spent significant time/effort attempting to address his question and offer improvements/suggestions that may have helped further. Not "offensive", but certainly rude. This is someone that IMHO doesn't deserve _my_ help in future, just as I'd be loathe to help anyone in my office that spoke to me like this.

Comment: @Anna so I take it such thing is not planned or being discussed?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It's not declined, but there are no immediate plans to implement it. This question picked up a flag along the lines of "status-deferred was added 3 years ago and it looks a bit silly", and I agree with that.

Comment: @AnnaLear it seems though that there is significant demand for it, though, with myself included

Comment: +1 - someone can attract my attention just by using my name. Some people aren't worth listening to. It would be great just to ignore them.

Comment: A bonus could be that, in the case of a heated dispute between two people that have been repeatedly asked to stop, moderators could enforce a temporary ignore on both parties without needing to resort to suspensions.

Comment: Got to this post because I was annoyed at a user and, as a human, went looking for something that would reinforce my point of view.  After reading the comment from @CodyGray and the following comment (_Take a sample from any real life society, and you're going to find personality disorders_) I'm giving them the benefit of the doubt and thinking they have a personality disorder.... would still like the ability to have someones posts appear in **Comic Sans** to remind me they are silly and shouldn't be listened to.

Comment: I like to block someone in the Delphi community, on every question, he is there. Every time something to mention that has nothing to do with the question. Or he doesn't read the question carefully/correctly or makes assumptions that is not related to question. This provokes irritation and clouded the question and if you do not agree with that, he will downvote (or his friends). So if it is possible to make a blacklist of users that are unable to view your question, cannot access the question, that would be a nice feature.

Comment: @Codebeat -  ⇙ - True. It's not necessarily the person's writing that is the problem, it's often their reading and comprehension / contextual skills that falter. They read a bit, somehow *know* the rest and post a comment; despite that they read some more and post again. Two red and no green always leaves me wondering if I should interrupt an important answer to deal with incomeless incoming interruptions (Ay-ay-ay).

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Nobody is reliably wrong about anything. Sometimes Moon landing deniers make more sense than some people who try (and sometime utterly fail) to debunk them (for lacking basic logic). In any case, incorrect claims and illogical attempts at reasoning should be refuted, not ignored.

Comment: The problem is worsened if the user in question is a _modera-troll_ adding unprofessional comments while editing one's questions/answers thinking they're all-powerful beings or something... A shame some people behave themselves with no sense of kindness...

Comment: You can ignore users in chat.

Comment: 11 year later, and no kill/ignore list.  It's worth noting that basically EVERY other social media site has kill/ignore lists. This goes back as far as usenet, and IRC. Neither usenet, nor IRC ever had these features built in, but they were always client features.  I think even reddit might have this as a special reddit plugin (reddit enhancement suite).  I haven't been on reddit in many years, but I think this still exists.  It'd sure be nice if there were just plugin specifically for SE that did stuff like this.

Comment: Even just hiding names of certain users would be great. People are abusing their usernames to ram their political statement of the day into a Q&A site, and there's nothing to report.

Comment: @CodyGray this is the most egregious example of unearned ignorant condescension I've ever seen. What's your advice then? "Grow up, snowflakes"? I've been pestered by this one pedant who appeared polite but was extremely irritating because he left incoherent chains of long drawn out comments pointing out how i should have been asking my questions instead of answering them or raising valid points. The same hypocrite that expected me to accept what he said as fact, while incessantly requiring me to cite better sources to his liking. I had to deal with this asshat for the last three goddamn days.

Comment: @CodyGray Unfortunately he never crossed any decorous line to be banned outright, and the flagging was pretty much futile, but his incessant pedantry cost me so much time arguing with his nonsensical points that I almost lost it. Guess what, sometimes people are just annoying and not worth listening to, the same way you could feel about anyone who's been pushing back against your ignorant "I'm not a snowflake like you pussies" argument.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a social medium, so why mention them as if Stack Exchange should follow their pattern or use them as examples of good practice? @SteveSether

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I'd love an ignore feature.

Related: [Greasemonkey: Ignore User Script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/greasemonkey-ignore-user-script)

Comment: This would be great for ignoring people whose opinions, as expressed in answers are part of a world view I do not embrace.

Comment: Be careful not to commit the *Genetic Fallacy* Mr. Williscroft :) Good answers are good answers regardless where they originate.

Comment: REAL ignore feature that keeps trolls from harassing other users, please.

Comment: You're my hero.  There's one user in particular who shows up seemingly *everywhere* to post inane drivel.  It's not objectively bad enough to merit a moderator flag, but it's annoying.  This will help tremendously!

Answer (score 121):

Stack Overflow is not meant to be a developer social networking Web site (this has been mentioned in the podcasts). It's a Q&A site. People are not at the forefront of Stack Overflow, **questions and answers** are.

Users are relevant for their *authorship*, not for their *presence*. There's absolutely no point in ignoring a *user*. You shouldn't really care *who says something* but rather, *what is said*.

You *can ignore tags* because they represent *content*, not *users*.

Comment: Technically, you're right. But the fact that we are having this discussion demonstrates that MetaSO is more social than many are ready to admit.

Comment: Anyhow, it's a place for discussion. You can either choose not to participate or if you do, listen to what everyone says and don't judge them by who they are. It's not a place for ad hominem arguments.

Comment: the problem is that many of us feel compelled to respond to ad hominem attacks directed at us, or misrepresentation of our own statements. it's human nature, and it is what the flame-baiting user counts on. the best solution, if the moderators don't agree that the user should be penalty boxed, is for us to ignore the user and go on with our life.  and it is easier to ignore what you can't see.

Comment: It might be human nature but humans should learn and practice not to give in to their emotions all the time.

Comment: (after heavy snipping) "Stack Overflow is not... a developer social networking Web site ... It's a Q&A site." Yeah, a community-driven Q&A site, which means it has to have some sort of community, which means it has to have certain features for this community.

Comment: Ignoring the user and concentrating just on what they say sounds somewhat reasonable...until the 10th time in a day when you see someone doing something that is rude and annoying.  Why should I subject myself to listening to someone on the vauge and unlikely hope that they'll eventually become tolerable?

Comment: beska: StackOverflow is not supposed to influence your life that way. If you find yourself in that situation, you should leave SO for a few hours IMO.

Comment: @Mehrdad: SO isn't supposed to influence my life in that way? I'm not supposed to find someone irritating if they act like a boor?  In general, this isn't an issue...the people here are usually grand.  But if I stepped away for a few hours every time this person irritated me, I'd spend a heck of a lot of time away.  And exactly what would that accomplish?  I'd come back, and that person would still be annoying, insulting, and unhelpful.

Comment: -1: Once the quality of the user has been identified, it can be used to guess the quality of their questions, answers, and comments.  If user A has determined that the cost of reading user B's posts often exceeds the value, then this feature would be quite handy.

Comment: Then why do we display badges?  Why do we display accept rate?  Why do we display user reputation next to every single one of their questions and answers?  We do we even have reputation?  Yes, the site is primarily about content, but we don't ignore the existence of the people behind the content.  The core reputation system *is* a social system, like it or not.  If we can reward good behavior, I don't see why we can't have tools to help us ignore bad behavior.

Comment: There is one user I really, really, really want to ignore.  He's developed quite a reputation for himself on Usenet (over a span of *years*) and on the Caml mailing list.  I would like to remove him from my SO experience.  The person is the source of consistently offensive content.

Comment: I would like to ignore Jitendra's questions.

Comment: So you intend to disregard the fact that users can consistently commit unuseful information. At that point.... why moderate? Why ban accounts?

Comment: @Xaada I'm not against banning a user by the system/community. I'm against individual blacklists.

Comment: I disagree, because the best predictor of future behavior is past behavior.

Comment: I have a limited amount of time I can dedicate to the community. I do occasionally identify Help Vampires and think it would be highly valuable to be able to not see contributions from such users. It means I will not waste my time on them and have more time to assist other members.

Comment: Social networking is a natural result of a commenting system that fosters attribution, even when pseudononymous.

Comment: `Stack Overflow is not meant to be a developer social networking Web site…`   Tell that to those who make comments purely to criticize and argue. Some people, upon seeing a q/a that has a error, instead of editing it to fix it or politely suggesting the fix in a comment, will instead make hostile, aggressive comments about the user being wrong and even down-vote the entire post. It’s difficult to ignore behavior like that because it is essentially an attack rather than a genuine attempt to be helpful. Worse, some people have OCD which makes simply ignoring and “moving on” *painful*.

Comment: `You shouldn't really care who says something but rather, what is said.` In general, I agree, but the two are not mutually exclusive. If *what* someone says is openly rude and hostile and highly suggests their further responses will be the same, it seems reasonable to want to minimize their interaction, at least within the scope of a single question. It's all too common for a user with a high reputation and a chip on their shoulder to call some question askers an idiot or insult them in a comment for perceived ignorance instead of actually answering their question.

Comment: I don't know what SE is "supposed" to be, but in actuality it IS a social network.  What it intends, or purports to be is immaterial.

Comment: The fact of the matter is that I do care about what is said. Even if what is said is repeatedly proven wrong or counterproductive, the user insists on fanning the flame to achieve some misguided sense of "victory".

Comment: This is a naive view. No one can sincerely deny that there are *personalities* on SE (esp. SO), who don't break the rules but who are nonetheless unpleasant and unhelpful repeatedly and consistently. Other users can have a very real and very legitimate desire to ignore certain *personalities* because it will objectively improve their user experience. We shouldn't have to flag every *annoying* post; the moderators have much better things to do than deal with my personal irritation with an obnoxious user. Just let me ignore them. All parties will be better off.

Comment: "People are not at the forefront of Stack Overflow" is an irrational take, given that this site is powered by unpaid human labor, not ChatGPT.

Answer (score 91):

See [here for my thoughts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/greasemonkey-ignore-user-script-now-includes-lists/3409#3409) on this; short version:

- I genuinely don't think the team should add this
- if an individual post offends you: flag that post
- if the mere existence of another user offends you: grow up

Comment: I don't think anybody suggested that they are offended/upset by the mere existence of another user. +1 though. I agree with everything else.

Comment: @Jonathan, when you suggest that you want to ignore EVERYTHING a user does, then you ARE in fact suggesting that you are offended by their existence on the site. You are saying "this person is beyond any sort of repair or compromise and I am not willing to try. So I would like them to disappear"

Comment: @devinb Do you think I place people in my ignore list prior to any engagement with them? No? Then it's not based on their existence. It's based on my interaction with them in the past. Right now, my list is 1 item deep. Based on several engagement with a particular user - not based on the users existence. Because I cannot programmatically determine the offensiveness of a particular statement, I've chosen to ignore everything. Frankly, nobody is hurt, and I am once again happy to visit MetaSO daily :)

Comment: I know you're busy and don't want to repeat yourself, but I wish you would expound more on your reasons here. I find them more compelling than Mehrdad's reasons, but I'm still not convinced.

Comment: I think Jonathan has nailed it here.  It's not the mere existence of a particular user that bothers people...it's the continued behaviors of that user.  Is it really more adult to say, well, "you've been rude and insulting the last 30 times I've read your comments, but I'll be forcing myself to read them anyway."  Why should people have to subject themselves to abuse just to be "grown up"?

Comment: Put another way, I think it is a bit more "adult" to just say, "well, I listened to this person for a while, but I am no longer interested in listening to them."  That seems fine.  I'm a bit loathe to flag every comment that is insulting because that seems a lot more like trying to force my beliefs on others...I'm basically saying "I don't like this person, and I don't think *anyone* should listen to them."  I'll do that for things that are really egregious, but I'd like to lean towards the side of tolerence, and just say, well, others can do what they want, but I'm done with you.

Comment: Marc, I'm tired of a user who is not egregious in invidual posts, but whose aggregate behavior is driving me up a tree.  Should I start flagging comments that are not individually egregious but which, in my opinion, are in aggregate a significant detriment to the community?

Comment: yes, flag start flagging comments that are not individually egregious but which, in my opinion, are in aggregate a significant detriment to the community

Comment: I've recently had some people randomly from nowhere attack me on a very personal level. They go to it with boundless energy, and they seem to hate me, even though I've only ever said a few words to them before. When they are being too obnoxious, their comments get deleted (evidence removed), in the mean time, they can drop innocent-looking remarks to goad me, such as nitpicking or making silly edits on my posts. Your advice is that I grow up. My advice is that Stackexchange grows up and becomes a site that cares about its members and takes a stand against internet bullies.

Comment: @TLP can you cite a specific example?

Comment: Like I said, the most obnoxious comments have all been removed. I have taken screenshots of some of the worst ones. What is it you are after? Here's the thing that happened today: http://imgur.com/peJVUuJ, though some of the comments have been deleted at this point. When this user could not get me to respond, he tried to make this rude-ish edit on one of my posts: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26363 Before this, I had a more severe one on stackoverflow.com, which I also have screenshots of. Here's one http://imgur.com/E5YP1aD

Comment: I am not looking for a trial on who is wrong and who is right, I just want to feel safe about adding content to Stackexchange sites without being harassed by these people who obviously have something against me personally.

Comment: @TLP well actually, in the Joffrey example, I think a very good case could me made that actually you were over-reacting and inflaming things, when the original discussion that you responded to was actually quite reasonable - but the key point here: *a moderator duly arrived and dealt with it*.

Comment: @MarcGravell Like I said, his two most damning comments had already been removed, where he became intensely personal. And really? You're defending *him* and saying that it was *my fault*? He came to *my answer*, long after it was posted, said I was not thinking straight and compared me to conspiracy theory nuts, and you are saying I should not have said anything about that, so as not to "inflame things"? I am grateful that Keen did tell him something, but this method of deleting evidence is quite bad. This way, abusers can just go on and on without consequence.

Comment: Your response also indicates that other people cannot accurately judge the individual reaction people have to comments. I am not a public service, it is not a human right to be able to address me and direct personal attacks at me when one gets angry. What I don't get is what the reasoning is for opposing the ability to block users? Am I expected to police abusive users by subjecting myself to their venom?

Comment: @TLP yes, I agree nobody has the right to direct personal attacks at you. The problem is: *I'm not seeing that* (and I can see the deleted ones, etc). Re why no blocking: because if there *were* abuse, that wouldn't make it go away. In the general case, it is preferable for it to at least be visible. Please: what scenario is *not* addressed by simply reporting such comments?

Comment: @MarcGravell If someone punches me in the face, and a referee comes in and wipes off the blood and deletes the security camera footage, then that does not do anything to alleviate my pain, or stop me from experiencing the next punch to the face. Especially since there is nothing to stop anyone from throwing another punch. When I become more passive because of flamers, that hurts the content of the website way, way more than if I would not report a handful of abusive comments.

Comment: You are wrong. If I can block someone's comment, then only I can't see it. If that comment is bad for someone other than me, then someone other than me can report it. If someone other than me won't report it, well then maybe it is not worth deleting. Thus, moderators have an easier time.

Comment: @TLP Sigh; "You are wrong." is not a helpful or constructive statement. Simply ignoring things is also not helpful, and making an "easier time" for the moderators by simply ignoring problems - equally unhelpful. Basically, we disagree here.

Comment: I hope you didn't just read the first 3 words, because the rest of that comment was constructive. It sounds like you have stopped listening, though, so I guess we're done. You were listening for a while, though, so I thank you for that.

Comment: @TLP I listened to the entire thing. I responded to multiple points. Just because I don't agree with you doesn't mean that I stopped listening.

Comment: @MarcGravell Well, it seemed like it to me. I did not say what you claimed I said. Even I don't agree with those opinions you mentioned. Who would ever think that ignoring abusive comments would help?

Comment: Or the other user should grow up.

Comment: At some point, I wonder if the mods have forgotten that this is not a forum, but an SE site.  Thanks for this very concise answer.

Comment: Given that you cannot write a 4 lines long answer without resorting to ad-hominem with your "grow up" comment, and that it did not get your post moderated in 10+ years, you're the poster boy for why being able to block people is a much needed feature.

Comment: @gallais I mean sure, if you think that suggesting people behave like adults (even when someone says something that we object to) is completely unacceptable, then I'm sure that the "block all the things" view of life is appealing

Comment: @MarcGravell Every single day you decide not to read articles, books, watch TV channels, youtube channels, etc. based on what you identify as worthy of your attention. THAT is being an adult. Not insulting people you don't agree with because you're afraid they might decide to ignore you.

Comment: @gallais the important difference being that in your examples you don't ask the world to erase all trace of them from your sight - you just... *ignore them all by yourself*; also: no insults have been offered to anyone.

Comment: @MarcGravell The suggestion of this post is literally "add the ability to ignore users", not a demand that the world erases them. You can't possibly be anything but a troll.

Comment: @gallais I am aware of the suggestion; my point is that we already have that capability; you're welcome to think what you like, but I fear you may be missing a great deal of context and history here

Comment: No we do not. That's like arguing that ad blockers are not needed because you can simply look away. It's utterly ridiculous, even baffling, that someone would adopt that line of thinking on a tech website.

Comment: @gallais genuinely: I've never used an ad blocker

Comment: "if an individual post offends you: flag that post" I think moderators have much better things to do than deal with my personal distaste for obnoxious people. "grow up" - Couldn't agree more. Growing up means ignoring people who irritate you rather than engaging with them or worse. That's a lot easier to do if I don't even have to see them.

Comment: "I fear you may be missing a great deal of context and history here" - for real? You're concerned that I'll miss out on some great piece of wisdom? I think I'll take my chances.

Answer (score 64):

Might be helpful in some scenarios, but... I'd feel pretty foolish if I posted a new comment/question/answer only to find out it was the exact duplicate of a very popular comment/question/answer posted an hour ago by someone I was ignoring.

[As Leaky notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users/3411#3411), this isn't a social networking site. If someone is annoying you *that much*, either they're using the site wrong or you are - either way, [the solution is for one/both of you to knock it off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users/3410#3410), not let one/both of you ignore it while the rest of us have to keep littering up the place.

This is declined for the main Q&A sites, but note that chat *is* meant as a social environment, and so it *does* have an "ignore" feature.

Comment: You could probably permit their questions - but ignore their comments/answers.

Comment: Perhaps you could make it ignore them like you can ignore specific tags? - That way when the system does it's magic search when you ask a question, it will bring back answers that you'd otherwise ignore.

Comment: @Jonathan: The same is true for answers. You could write the same thing as answer someone on your ignore list did 2 hours ago. Then be not surprised, if you are downvoted ;-)

Comment: you wouldn't feel foolish if you couldn't have seen that post ;)

Comment: Further, "I didn't see it because I was ignoring that user" should not in any way be grounds to prevent deletion of your duplicate answer/comment.  So you'll have done extra work, and consumed reviewers' or moderators' time, for nothing in the end.

Comment: I think this answer is the best I've read so far. So, I think in light of your answer, an alternative solution would be in order. I mean, like instead of hiding their content from you, just make your content read-only to them.

Comment: Agreed with @Sampson; ignore comments only, not Q&A. Comments are borderline between content and chat but they too often fall on the chat side. Or maybe even give users the ability to opt out of commenting *entirely*.

Answer (score 41):

2021 Update: Just marked this as [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred). We will consider this request as part of a larger inquiry into abuse and how to mitigate it. This is not on our roadmap in the near future.

2018 Answer:

#### We're going to consider this.

This didn't make as much sense in 2009 as it does today mostly because in 2009, people came here *for* the rules; they were fed up with other platforms where the noise far outweighed the signal *and at that time* a little abrasiveness, even when kinda obsessive, was a price most were okay with paying for high signal with very little noise or distraction. I think even I said 'get a thick skin' back then ***and that was one of the wrongest things I think I ever said*** given what I've learned since then.

Putting something like this in place back then kind of felt like giving in before we figured out how far forward we could push without it. Twitter dog piles back then weren't very common, nor was people cycling through dozens of bogus accounts to deliberately target and harass people, which is unfortunately something that keeps the community growth team busy.

We're going to take a look at this through (what I fear) is going to be rather painful analysis and look at all of the ways where the option to mute interactions in a more granular way might make a *bit* more sense. The goal here: Let people turn off specific kinds of noise at certain thresholds, but don't *hide* abuse that we really need to be dealing with at a lower level by simply burying it.

We also don't want new users just cramming their fingers in their ears, which could be tempting if they get off on the wrong foot. Changes here have to fit in closely with changes to help users post better questions to begin with.

I don't have an ETA but as we look at ways that we can make people more confident that they have *some* control over what rings the inbox notifier, it could serve as a last stop above the current level of toxicity that some have been reporting.

#### And before you go nuts, I said *consider*

When / if we roll this out it will be much more considered than "just build a per-user mute button". We have to look at other aspects of the software that lead some folks to believe that 'mutable' behavior is acceptable if you're a good enough rule lawyer, and put our 'be nice' policy more in front of people as a solid code of conduct with advertised and consistent consequences.

So, yeah - we have to keep up with the times, and maybe we waited a little too long in this (and other) areas of the site to finally accept that there are social aspects where we need to be much more influential, if not in complete control.

We're going to take a look, and there will be a separate (2018 version) discussion once we've got some ideas.

Thanks for poking this.

Comment: Thanks for considering this. Things sure were different in 2009... :)

Comment: Muting another user seems like a (very useful) workaround to a deeper problem: comment sections are treated as discussion forums. For instance, over on Interpersonal Skills, [comments tend to be used to kibitz](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2807/8) rather than annotate posts. [Killfiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_file) (which is what the proposed feature is) didn't prevent problems in groups so much as make the group more livable for people who used them. In particular, they don't help new users who don't know about the feature yet.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you're looking into this thorny problem with complicated edge cases.  Please also consider [a simpler solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309162/162102) in your deliberations.  Thank you.

Comment: Well, there won't be a separate (2018 version) discussion now, I guess? Unless there was and I missed it?

Comment: Any odds we can get an update on this? It would be increasingly welcome on History and Politics to ignore our handful of resident trolls. I should raise in passing, though, that if high rep users are all ignoring said trolls instead of flagging what they write on a regular basis, the feature might have unintended negative consequences.

Comment: What's going on now? It's been almost 1.5 years in review? Thanks!

Comment: @Stormblessed I think we're ultimately going to try having the option to stop notifications on a _per post_ basis, but I don't have a timeline for it. The use case: You want to get out of a heated discussion in comments and have a hard time disengaging with your inbox lighting up. My hope is maybe before the end of the year (2019) but I can't promise anything yet.

Comment: I'm glad to see this functionality would be limited to a per Post basis. People already have the right to demand _how_ to get addressed. If this would be extended to _who_ can address them, there would be a major imbalance between the rights of the addresser and addressee.

Comment: Where can we find the "separate (2018 version) discussion" or whatever the most recent discussion is on the subject?

Comment: A simple, non-confrontational compromise solution might be this: Just make it so the people you 'ignore' never see your updates in the main page feed, unless they bump them themselves. They could still find them through other routes. Don't do anything else. It would solve about 96% of the problems, probably, and they couldn't even tell you were ignoring them (unless they paid way too much attention). They could still search for your posts explicitly, and comment, though, but by the time they found them, they wouldn't be able to do as much damage.

Comment: @JonEricson A comment is a discussion. Someone writes an answer and somebody else replies to the answer by a comment. It is small but it is a discussion. Allowing comments while claiming "but you are not allowed to discuss" is silly nonsense.

Comment: @AnitaTaylor "This is not on our roadmap in the near future" - in other cases this leads to [tag:status-declined]. What's the difference here? Why deferred instead of declined? Is it random?

Comment: Is this still under consideration? I would support allowing ignoring of users for purposes of comments and chat if not for QA. Alternatively let us opt out of comments entirely so we can really stick to the point of the site.

Answer (score 39):

**Similar to Usenet KILLFILE**

I like this idea.  From Usenet experience, there's always a couple of odd characters who seem to contribute little to discussions but are able to stir up way more than their share of controversy.

It's nice to be able to just ignore the controversy.  Plus it gives people the ever-satisfactory rejoinder to any disagreement, "that's it, you're going into
my killfile!"

As a practical thing, it might be useful to moderators to see which users are being ignored by lots of other users.

Comment: SE is not for discussions. Don't have them.

Comment: @Raedwald What else but a discussion is this thread?

Comment: @ceving Meta is different

Answer (score 33):

Every possible feature must be examined with a few variables in mind.

- How does this benefit individual users (consumers)
- How does this benefit all users (community)
- How does this contribute to the goals of the site

**How does this benefit individual users**

This can be subdivided into three categories: **Ignorers**, **Problem Users**, **Bystanders**

**Ignorers**

This group benefits the most, obviously. There is some user that they do not want to see anymore. Those comments will disappear, those answers will disappear, and those questions will disappear. The minor consistency problems with this have been [illustrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users/47279#47279) [already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users/3362#3362). But those could be mitigated by simply having an 'IgnoredComment' pop-up of some kind. Configurable, of course. Like the ignored tags.

The downside is that this user could *potentially* miss out on a good question or good answer. But it's a huge community, so they probably wouldn't be missed. The ignorers will end up being more productive and happier as a result.

**Problem Users**

These users are annoying. They're not offensive, otherwise their comments could be flagged as offensive. They are not spamming, otherwise their comments/questions could be flagged as spam. The behaviours that they are exhibiting are simply annoying for whatever reason. The moderators cannot do anything because they are not breaking any rules. So they simply continue to exist and make life worse for those around them.

Once they are being ignored, they have *no way of knowing it*. They are not being told to get better, they will not notice that they are being ignored. There will be literally no indication to them that they are expected to improve. Furthermore, if someone does tell them to improve (someone who has helpfully *not* put them on ignore) and they DO improve, they will still be on ignore lists, which means that their past behaviour precludes them from fully participating ever again. As one poster points out: [being NEW is considered crime enough to put them on the ignore list.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users/22294#22294)

This also means that users are [punished for disagreement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users/3471#3471). I am someone who believes that many architecture decisions are complex, and therefore there can be many contradictory but independently correct solutions. This means that there will be arguments. I will downvote and comment on questions, and the author will clearly disagree with me. If that user gets frustrated with me, they could just say "I'm ignoring you!" and then feel smugly superior, like they won the argument. In fact, they are simply running away. They have no convinced me of their opinion, they have not convinced me to *change my behaviour*. Especially on meta, where discussion (heated sometimes) is encouraged, this feature would be counter-productive. You would lose out on voices of dissent. I'm not saying that these people are right, but if you just white-wash and convince yourself that no one disagrees, then you are LOSING out on valuable input.

Furthermore, if there is as few as *one* incident, they can be ignored. And there is no way to redeem yourself. You are just gone. This goes against the point of SO, where content is judged individually, and the votes speak for themselves.

The **Problem Users** who, as I've highlighted, are not necessarily problematic at all, will have a much much worse user experience, with *no guidance as to how to improve*.

**Bystanders**

Bystanders are everyone else involved. If the ignorers start ignoring people, the bystanders still have to see them. But, there will be fewer people actually trying to help those problematic users. It means that for the bystanders (the bulk of the community) the general product will be worse. The annoying people are still being annoying, but there are fewer people reporting them. If they attempt to answer a question for a user who is on many people's [ignored] list, then there will be fewer people to comment and provide feedback. If they edit a bad question and make it better, this will also be [ignored] by those ignorers. Ultimately, it means that the bystanders will end up seeing *less* information from the good users, and *more* information from the bad users, because there are fewer people trying to keep the content-to-noise ratio down.

For bystanders, the net result will be bad.

**How does this benefit all users**

As I said in the bystanders section. This feature is anti-community. It encourages us to ignore problems rather than try to solve them (an interesting position on a *problem solving* website). The bad users are still bad, but no one is going to make them better. The reason this community is so strong is that it takes good programmers and makes them better, and it takes bad programmers and makes them into good ones. Those programmers will then become huge advocates who will contribute strongly to the community.

But that won't happen anymore. We are writing off people who *need improvement*. We are also writing off people who have abrasive personalities, despite the positive things they could contribute.

Another aspect to consider is the effect on new users. I'll illustrate with a trivial/silly example (please don't extend this past the purpose I'm bringing here) If you live in a messy apartment, but you just ignore the mess, and live there just fine. *Every new person* you show your apartment to is going to comment on the mess. But you don't notice anymore, so you think it's fine.

New users are going to find that there is a lot of spam, and a lot of annoying users. This will cause them to turn around and leave. Yes there is an "ignore user" option, but they won't know about that initially, *and* they won't bother with trying to get value from the site, when it is clearly just overrun with spam.

**How does this contribute to the goals of the site**

The goal of the site is to be a repository of information. That means, taking common questions and putting them in front of as many people as possible, and letting the best answers be decided by the community. Adding the ability to ignore users means that the questions (which could be useful to everyone) will no longer be seen by everyone. That means that users who could have provided incredible answers that were read by *everyone* will now not do so, just because the *question asker* did not meet their personal standards.

Ultimately, this feature does not contribute to the goals of the site.

**Breakdown**

Benefit to individual users: Ignorers: **Positive**
Benefit to individual users: Ignored: **Very Negative**
Benefit to individual users: Bystanders: **Negative**

Benefit to community: **Negative**

Contribute to site goals: **Mostly Negative**

**SOLUTIONS**

Just move on. If their comments annoy you, move on.

If their comments are offensive. Flag them.

If their questions are spam/offensive/argumentative. Flag them. Close them. Report them.

Lastly, (for those with the strength of will) *engage them*. **Try to help them.** Why are they argumentative? Are they naturally douchey, is there a language barrier, do they have an aggressive oratorical style? Did their wife just cheat on them with their best friend and that bitch wants my car now too?

I can't rule any of those things out, and I really don't care. I just want to contribute to this community as much as I can.

Comment: Great analysis, +1

Comment: there are ways around some of the problems you raise. first, ignoring a user could automatically flag that comment. if a user is ignored by several people, moderators can investigate and the user might be warned or put in the penalty box. second, the ignores could expire after, say, 2 months. mostly you would ignore in the heat of the moment when someone is provoking you. and lastly, i don't think we'd see a site full of jerks that all the regulars ignore. ignoring would probably be done by a few users in a few cases. if someone gets ignored by everyone then they should probably be banned.

Comment: "Ignoring a user could automatically flag that comment." This makes assumptions about implementation details. Also, if the comment is worth flagging then **flag it**. If a users comments are repeatedly flagged, they will be removed or penalty boxed. On the other hand, if the users comments aren't flaggable, then reporting them wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: Second, having expiration date on the ignore is extremely counter-intuitive and harms usability. If you're ignoring someone, you are saying they aren't worth your time. This suggestion actually dilutes your own argument because you're saying "well, I only want to ignore them for as long as they are annoying me" which would be a great feature, but it is impossible.

Comment: Third your "Ignoring would probably done by a few users in a few cases" is (strawman ahead) a great argument for legalizing murder. That's a bad example (I know). But you are saying that you want this feature even though you wouldn't want it to actually be used by everyone. Features are created to be *used*. If that use is harmful, then they should not be *created at all*.

Comment: i'm not saying that i wouldn't *want* it to actually be used by everyone. i'm saying that it simply *wouldn't* actually be used by everyone. features are created to be used *where appropriate*. i don't see the situation where someone ignores someone happening all that often, unless the site starts attracting the kind of people who leave comments on YouTube. and if it turns out that the feature is being overused, then it could be reevaluated. it's not like any of the rules are set in stone here (i.e. the global rep recalc).

Comment: @Kip means the feature wouldn't shouldn't be arbitrarily used. Likewise neither should moderation. The fact of the matter is there are two users that if I didn't have to see, I would participate more. Sure I could be a little more mature and ignore them in my head. However, you can't make a horse drink. This is a content site, and not giving users control over what content they can see will result in them doing it themselves (Greasemonkey), which means the control of that feature is out of the hands of the community.

Comment: Let my abrasive personality wholeheartedly applaud this answer! There is one important question missing near the end, _"Consider the possibility you are possibly being abrasive yourself?"_

Comment: "Just move on."  Can't we write a program to do it for me?

Comment: for such a long-winded rant, it sure is naive.   What one person considers a problem, another might not.  You end up with massive power discrepancies and disagreements on what is appropriate which can only make one side happy.  If you're in the "have" group, you're good.  if you're in the "have not" group, you're SOL.   Sounds like you're in the former.

Comment: `For bystanders, the net result will be bad.` You're assuming that forcing the "Ignorers" to not ignore people will mean they'll continue helping "Problem users". That's simply not the case. If a user is so annoying that they make another user want to purge them from their view, it's unlikely that they're going to help them. It's just the opposite. Allowing them to ignore annoying users will keep them on the site helping other users. Forcing them to see annoying users will worsen their site experience, making them likely to leave or help other users.

Comment: I've never heard anyone say, "Boy, I can't wait to login to Youtube and read all those wonderful comments!" The conventional wisdom is, "Don't read Youtube comments because they cause cancer." Stackexchange is a long way from Youtube, but it should still be trying to avoid these common problems.

Comment: This is a great analysis but I'm sorry to say ultimately it's naive to think that the "problem users" will improve. And regardless it shouldn't be our job to help them improve. I just want a pleasant experience. If my experience can be improved by not seeing the same irritating people's names show up repeatedly in my inbox or on the posts I like to read, realistically no one else loses out because of that. But if you're really afraid it'll be abused, limit the ignore list to maybe 5 people. Then it won't just get used every time someone merely disagrees with you.

Answer (score 29):

As you note in the quote at the end of the question, part of the problem is that moderators have only big sticks.  Ignoring users who you know get under your skin is attractive, and I'm glad to see that the team will [evaluate this problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309160/162102), but it's a complicated problem with a lot of edge cases.  Another way to approach the problem is to **give moderators the ability to ban users from commenting**.

We can already manually block bad reviewers, and the system automatically blocks new questions (or sometimes answers) from users with poor track records.  The one-size-fits-all suspension has *already* been broken up.  Except for comments.  Some of the sites I participate on get a *lot* of comments, many of which need to be deleted, but, often, individual cases don't rise to the level of suspensions.  But if I could say "you there! no commenting for you for the next week!", I'd use that in an instant to quell rising heat levels on my sites.  Incidents should be logged with the user (as other bans are) for easy review; if a track record emerges, then we can suspend in good conscience instead of the constant questioning and endless review of deleted comments that we have to do now.

Yes, please think about the larger ignore problem too, but please give us a comment ban in the meantime!

Comment: Or give moderators the ability to revoke the "comment anywhere" privilege... unless that's what you meant? When you say "comment lock" I think "lock the comments on the post", not "prevent a user from commenting at all on the site"...

Comment: Sorry, I meant comment ban, like edit bans.  Will fix when back at a desktop (if somebody else hasn't already).

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365811/can-we-do-more-than-just-delete-rude-comments

Comment: Looks like it's already status declined by Tim at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300571/please-give-the-moderators-option-to-revoke-the-privilege-for-commenting

Comment: @JonClements the current request was status-declined until yesterday; since we're reopening it, I figured it was worth re-raising a related request.

Answer (score 16):

This needs to be revisited. If not the ability to ignore a user completely, then I'd at least like the option to have posts from specific users *not* give me a notification. (Like Yvette Colomb's [Can we have a feature to ignore specific user's pings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277144/1288))

Also the ability to mute all future notifications from a specific post would be great. (For those times when you just want to answer programming questions, but notifications from a post a few days old keep popping up...)

Comment: Ignoring a post's comments would be really nice. I've some posts on Politics (and one on SO Meta) that continue to attract comments years later.

Comment: This is a great idea, I hope it's re-visited. In fact, it's "the" feature I actually want. I wanted "ignore" solely to avoid the pings (from certain members).

Answer (score 14):

Users who are annoying for whatever reason are definitely a problem, but I question whether this solution could be implemented well.  Turning on "Ignore" functionality almost always leads to consequences that are different than the original problem, but just as bad.  Simple example:

> *Alice is ignoring Bob, but otherwise everyone can see everything.*
>
> Alice: [relevant comment]
>   Bob: [trollish comment]
>   Carl: [something along the lines of "shut up and go away"]
>   Alice: Hey, what was that for?

Adding things like only ignoring comments or only ignoring questions makes the whole mess even stickier.

Comment: [trollish comment]

Comment: Hmmm... [feature-request] Allow me to use all of my comment votes for one day on a single comment.

Comment: of course, the same thing happens today if bob deletes his own comment, or if a moderator deletes bob's comment

Comment: @Kip: true, but that's only motivation to come up with an even better solution, like @mvid's.

Comment: @Bob: Well played, old chap. Well played!

Comment: Wouldn't Carl say "@Bob: Shut up and go away", not just "Shut up and go away"?

Comment: or even worse: alice starts ignoring carl

Answer (score 12):

This feature really needs to be reevaluated given that's been a couple years since it was declined. This could also allow the network infrastructure to [allow people to feel more comfortable here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334058/are-there-specific-issues-with-unwelcoming-behavior-toward-lgbtq-persons-on-stac).

[image]

Comment: Preferably in the form of "click here to show message from ignored user", similar to ignoring users in discord so that if you want to, you can easily follow along a conversation.

Comment: Yes. I’d love to see this feature as well. Each stack has its own personality, and each mod team, their own level of tolerance. The same way twitter lets me block offensive members in my feed, I’d be happy to be able to do the same here.

Comment: @Joe, *The same way twitter lets me block offensive members in my feed, I’d be happy to be able to do the same here.* That goes a long way in explaining the behavior of some users here. However, Stack Exchange was never envisioned as a social network, and many of us love it *because of this*. We are not supposed to be Facebook. We are not supposed to be Twitter.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I've been a member for nearly 10yrs and a Mod on one stack for 5. This year was the first time I wished for this feature. On one stack, where a member feels compelled to comment with 3-5 comments on nearly every question. And targets members they don't care for, with dozens of comments. I needed to turn off my iOS alert on my phone as this was reaching 'stalker' level. Mods, as is their discretion, feel the behavior does not rise to 'suspension' or even warning level. If you felt harassed like this, you might wish for the same feature. It only takes one.

Comment: @Joe, I was under the impression that flagging enough comments from such a user would result in warnings from the mod team first, suspension second, and does arguably solve the problem (albeit not immediately). Ignoring such users does not strike me as begin as efficient -- after all the offending comments would still be there.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I'm sorry to get into a debate, but let me say that a dozen nasty comments, posted so I see them (via ping), then removed minutes later, cancel the flag off.  And the member had a months long tirade telling a Mod to "do your effing job", and right after, going back to talking about the weather. She put him through 10X worse than me.  So for now, I'll ignore, and not interact.   Not all mods handle things the same, nor as I would.

Comment: @Joe, thank you for replying, and please don't be sorry -- as you know, Meta was intended as a debate space as well as a bug report / feature request venue. There will be two comments. In this one, I agree with you that there are "toxic" (`$DEITY`, I hate that word, but I have no alternative) people out there and dealing with them tears you out. And I agree the moderation team is not big enough to handle the load (even less so now). But it does not mean you have to *ignore* people. *Ignoring* is wrong, because someday they *may* be right, but you won't hear them.

Comment: Now I would like to focus on the technical side of things and ask you about something that I did not know about, namely *let me say that a dozen nasty comments, posted so I see them (via ping), then removed minutes later,* ***cancel the flag off*** (emphasis mine). I have never heard about that (and I've been here for a while). If true, it would explain (and change) a lot of things, and might be worthy of its own question on Meta. Can you tell me more?

Comment: I may be mixing issues, but I’m pretty certain that after I flagged, the OP quickly deleted her comment, and the flag was no longer there for the stack mods to see. Either way, I understand that on the stack where I am a mod, I have an implied agreement to be kind and interface with all members. On other stacks, with a particular other member , enough is enough.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - [This](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/17344/explaining-why-or-whether-zero-and-one-are-prime-composite-or-neither-to-youn) is one such example. If I were the OP of one of these answers, I wouldn't appreciate 7 pings. Is there ever a need for 7 comments on one answer, not to mention the 10 more on others? When a member does this on the site I mod, I shut it down quickly, as we are not a 'discussion board'. There, not so much.

Comment: Sorry for the extra ping. The OP deleted his answer as the multiple comments were (in my opinion) bullying him to do so. So I doubt you'd even see what just happened. No big deal, just a miss on a great example.

Answer (score 11):

If we're following the xbox live model, well they have flagging... and they have mute. was that a mistake then?

My view is that if the lack of a mute feature causes someone to want to not spend time on SO, well that's a serious problem for SO. It does not seem that the penalty box has been a sufficient deterrent.

Comment: But the "ignore feature" and "penalty box" have different goals. One is for self-gratification, the other is for community improvement. If, as you say, the penalty box is insufficient deterrent (I TOTALLY agree) then we should *improve* the ability of the moderators and the community to help/encourage users to stop being problems. We should focus on features and methods which are geared towards community improvement.

Comment: @devinb: In principle I'd completely agree, but in practice I think all attempts are doomed to failure for at least some cases and I'd rather provide a nuclear option. Hopefully you don't have to use it.

Comment: The ignore feature can be just as much for community improvement. It encourages people to participate that otherwise would stop. It encourages people to be nice knowing they might be ignored.

Answer (score 11):

What if we filtered users the same way we filter tags? The responses are still there, just kind of grayed out. You can still see the actual content (for dupe purposes), but it is not going to jump out at you.

It could also work the opposite way, allowing you to hilight users you believe are more knowledgeable/useful.

Comment: *"The responses are still there, just kind of grayed out."*  Yep.  Spot on, I think this serves the 'best of all worlds'.

Comment: And sadly, your nice idea seems to have been ignored.

Answer (score 9):

While [Hellbanning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93806/is-there-going-to-be-a-process-around-hellbanning/93809#93809) is distinctly different, the anti-community results are remarkably similar.

Stack Overflow is about content, not about people.  You can't "friend" people, so therefore you can't "unfriend" or worse - "block" people.

You can show interest or disinterest in topics and tags.

You can upvote and downvote specific solutions.

You can flag and tag content.

These are the weapons and tools provided, and they are focused solely on content.

The one and only limited person based thing we have we do not hand to the users - only moderators can ban users/people.

Allowing users to target other users, even for only their consumption, is too user-focused and not enough content-focused.

Use the tools provided, and if they are inadequate, describe a content-based tool which would resolve the issue, rather than a user-based tool.

Comment: There is no content-based tool to deal with one user harassing another. This insistence that this is not a social network, therefore we don't have social network problems, is just ignoring real issues. We need to pull our heads out of the sand.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Flagging for moderator attention doesn't work? How prevalent is this problem?  Are bad actors actively going around and harassing specific users without being caught and punished? Or are they not caught and punished enough? What level of harassment are we talking about, because outright insults, swearing, etc should be easily handled and result in bans from the moderators.  Or am I mistaken and the site has a lot of bad actors, operating openly, without reprise, with terrible forms of harassment?  This request would benefit from some statistics and knowledge of degree.

Comment: Because my interpretation of this question isn't an issue of harassment - they don't want the user banned or their content deleted.  They've just found that their writing style rubs them the wrong way, and therefore don't want to see it - not that it's bad content, or that the person is bad, but that the two of them together result in friction.  You're speaking of acts of harassment, though.

Comment: Victims of harassment don't often post details and statistics in the place where they're being harassed, for fear of more harassment. And yes, `I had a problem, reported it and got the response "not bad enough to do anything about, sorry". `

Comment: @BilltheLizard Ok, so this is about harassment.  I feel that's distinctly different, and that the attacker should be stopped at the system level, not just the user level.  Can you describe a scenario where someone is harassing someone else, but their content is not only completely in line with the site guidelines, but valid and valuable to other users, and they are not bothering any other user, just the one?  Because that's the *only* situation where I could see this solution being correct.  And then only if it's a persistent, prevalent problem that cannot be handled on a case by case basis.

Comment: As it is, a userscript should resolve the situation for a handful of people with this issue.  The question I need answered is whether the problem is pervasive enough that we really need to change the whole system to take care of it.

Comment: And as far as posting stats, that should come from the mods and stackoverflow.  They should have a pretty good handle on how many people are complaining about this type of personal harassment.

Comment: As it is we've only got 236 people (out of millions of users) who've upvoted this in the last decade.  Very few have posted anything similar to *"I've experienced this kind of harrasment"*.

Comment: A user is currently camping out on one of my posts from two days ago, responding to every answer and comment, even if they're not directed at that user. They're not breaking any rules, but they're dominating the conversation there. I'd like to just mute that user and/or post, but the tools don't currently allow me to. I'm pretty much left with ignoring all notifications. (This is not the first time this has happened, and it is not the only user that does it. I typically just avoid all Meta discussions lately because of this kind of behavior.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard That does sound annoying.

Comment: Muting posts would be a damn useful feature even outside of overtly abusive situations.

Comment: Fwiw, we briefly tested a "report user" function s few years back... Most of the reports were specific to something a user had written (spam, trolling) and thus merely delayed the removal of problematic content; of the rest, a significant portion was folks upset that someone had criticized their post. Also, lots of reports on  moderators.

Answer (score 8):

[Something like this](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/91097-ignore-certain-users-option) was declined on UV, but there weren't any reasons given, so I can only guess.  I think Jeff's preferred solution is to warn such a person, use the [penalty box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) if need be, and if they fail to shape up, take more drastic action:

> (This should probably go without
> saying, but if the problem behaviors
> continue beyond the timed suspension,
> your account is very likely to be
> permanently deleted.)

Further, in systems where I've seen an ignore feature implemented, it always results in confusion.  People appear to answering questions that nobody has asked, non-sequiturs abound, information gets duplicated.  I don't favor it for this reason.

### EDIT:

The whole Greasemonkey thing had me thinking about this again.  How would ignoring even help in the case of an edit-war, like one that hypothetically, maybe, allegedly, theoretically inspired this thread?

Comment: @Pesto: Shhhhhhhhh.

Comment: @Pesto: this particular post inspired by flame wars in comments rather than edit wars.

Answer (score 8):

Well, if I were sandboxed from their actions, that means I could sandbox myself off from the experts of a particular tag. And if I did that, it might mean that only people with less subject knowledge than you could think your answer was wizz-bang, while an expert might have a serious objection to the answer.

Reputation means that the system trusts you, so you shouldn't be able to be shielded from anybody whose reputation is significantly higher than yours. Unfortunately that means that you could be subject to some high-rep curmudgeons.

But everything's a tradeoff.

Comment: _"high-rep curmudgeons"_ Love it.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps this concept could be extended; when a question gets enough downvotes, it can be closed.  Similarly, if a user gets enough "ignores", perhaps their behavior can be flagged for review / probation / whatever.

This would serve a different purpose than flagging a post; flagging a post indicates that **the post** is offensive.  Ignoring a user indicates that the "ignorer" finds the "ignoree" so offensive that they don't care whatever they say.  Plus, if I'm ignoring the user, I won't end up flagging their posts, which could tend to mean that their offensive behavior gets "unflagged" long enough to offend more new users who haven't learned to ignore that user.

Comment: Well... there's *already* a "flag" feature.

Comment: Just flag the post.

Comment: Flagging doesn't seem to get much done, to be honest.

Comment: @McWaffleStix: That is not what I have found. Perhaps you are not flagging things that actually require action?

Answer (score 7):

I like this idea, I would use it for other purposes too.

- Sometimes someone pops up and quickly asks a flurry of beginner questions on one of my interesting tags. Nothing wrong with that, but I prefer to leave them to other people to answer, and I don't find the discussions interesting either. I'd like to ignore their questions - just a personal decision. I know, it's probably bad karma.
- This is rarer, but I've noticed some people are very free with downvotes. I've posted (IMHO) quite nice answers on their questions, and they downvote because of a niggle with my phrasing. I check their homepage, and they dish out 10x more downvotes than upvotes. Again, a personal decision but I prefer to avoid their questions in future. Not just because I'm rep farming, but it's just a discouraging scene.

I would not ignore these people's answers or comments, just their questions.

Comment: why ignore beginner questions, if you can provide good answers to them?

Comment: @warren: Because, for whatever reason, he's not interested in answering them.  There's no quota he has to fill.  Rep is designed to encourage answering, but answering questions isn't required.

Comment: @beska - true enough it's not "required".. I guess I'm wondering how do you classify "beginner"? Beginner to the whole process? In that language/tag? I could see those self-same "beginner" questions and have no clue because it's an area I know nothing about, or I think is more advanced than where I am.

Comment: @warren, @beska Nice of you to stop by :) There was a couple of users posting many beginner type questions - which is fine. But they didn't seem to benefit from the answers. I noticed them asking effectively the same question five or six times over several months, and they didn't seem to learn anything. I tried to politely point out that the questions were effectively duplicates, and the answers they'd accepted should mean the later questions were unnecessary. But there was no response. In the end I gave up on them (though the community kept helping them - it was a personal choice)

Comment: (-1) I disagree with you. Please see my response.

Comment: @devinb Fair enough. I will continue manually ignoring people.

Answer (score 7):

I think one of the bit arguments against is that by design SE is supposed to be aggressively meritocratic. By blocking yourself from seeing specific users - you're more or less making it about the *poster* not the *content*.

As per the original question and many of the answers - well we shouldn't be seeing flamebait if people focus on the problems at hand. Even on the newer, subjective sites, I think our core goal - to get people useful, practical answers to real problems is important.

*However* with broadening scopes, not all sites have objective, purely technical scopes so having this as a option on *some* sites could be worth considering, other than these sites have *more* problems with folks not getting along, not less and being able to hide posts kind of just sticks a bandaid over a broader issue.

I can see some people benefiting from being able to block seeing *comments* but blocks on posts feels kind of against the 'ethos' of SE as a whole.

Comment: Many of my Q and A were considered too provocative or bait, until I had the time to explain the misunderstood details and then ppl ended up agreeing with me. Sometimes they get deleted and the debate is shut down. More suppression is not a solution to anything.

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to the alleged opinion here, silencing certain users has made my experience here considerably greater. Keep in mind that the [ignore-users script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script) isn't a solution to bad-behavior here. **Reporting to Mods is the preferred solution.** The ignore-script is a hold-over, or an extra-jump if you absolutely need silence.

Comment: I sense you're expecting harsh criticisms for this post based on the fact that you wiki'd it.

Comment: @Ian: Which is pretty much the definition of trolling.

Comment: @Jonathan: Sasha's not suggesting an "ignore" feature - he's suggestion a system that would effectively let you choose who could vote and comment on your posts. Ignoring other users is your prerogative - if you use a script to help you do that, fine. But opting out of SO's feedback systems is something else entirely.

Comment: @Jonathan - thanks for the script.  I can;t wait to start using it

Answer (score 6):

I retract my previous answer having gained more knowledge of the site.

Blocking users or content in any way would be detrimental to us helping each other.
Sure I get frustrated with other users sometimes, but, there are times with users I'm familiar with where I've mostly liked their comments, I've then seen them post something I felt was rude, or stupid, etc.
Had I seen those bad comments first, I might have "blocked" them and not seen their better comments.

We can all have an off day, can't we?

We're a wild bunch of folks from all walks of life with so many varying opinions, and we will get on each others tips now and then.
That doesn't mean we should block each other.

The point is not to block each other out, but to learn to tolerate our differences.

Besides, if we block that annoying user, how can we argue with them next time :D

---

I might be behind a way to mark users as good or bad. This is better, although still against the spirit of a community.

Something like:
A function where we can click a username and mark that user as "Good" or "Bad", and neutral (which would be as it is now).

Then anywhere their name appears in comments (and even questions and answers) their name is GREEN for good and RED for bad.

Of course allow it so we can revert to Good, Bad, or neutral, regardless of the current setting.

This would allow any users to be "ignored" without removing their content.
This resolves:

1. Still see potentially valuable posts - a user annoying you (or
   whatever) in one post or several doesn't mean they don't have a
   comment (or answer or question) which is very useful to you
2. Able to revert from good/bad/default allows us to change our minds,
   and a system outright blocking content doesn't allow us to identify
   when we've been a little hasty or harsh on a user for a few posts.
   With the username just coloured, we can still see their other
   content and decide they just had a bad day, or *we* had a bad day
   and didn't want to block them really.
3. While the content can still be seen by the user marked as "bad" on
   your list, their username being RED means easy to ignore (more than
   now anyway).

Answer (score 5):

Anyone offensive enough for you to ignore is offensive enough for you to report to the Stack Overflow team.

They are quite effective at cracking down on offensive users.

Comment: I have to say this isn't true (and with good reason). I had a problem, reported it and got the response "not bad enough to do anything about, sorry". Which is kind of true, because the only options available to the mods are the nuclear one (penalty box) and the zero-effect one, (do nothing). We need a middle ground option where abuse can be handled *for you* without also being handled *for everyone*. Kyle's point #6 in the question is a good reason for this too.

Comment: @annakata: moderators do actually have a few other tools... They can lock disputed posts 'till things cool down, they can merge questions (rather than leaving an argument over whether it's a duplicate or not to sit and brew), and they can instantly delete questions (drastic, but still an action against a question rather than a user). IMHO, these tools are *almost always* more appropriate than any punitive action against a specific user.

Comment: This was posted 6 years ago... yet the behavior many have requested this feature for is still rampant. I feel very safe in saying it's not going to be fixed and a different path is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

This feature would be cool, because I'm sure most of you know the feeling, when you just think someone should shut up, even if they weren't breaking rules.

To avoid awkward situations described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47279/305460) I have a **slighly different solution** than the questioner:

Problem users should just be blocked from questions of the ignorers, so there won't be any good answers missed because they simply can't answer to the question. In all questions from different users the Ignorers will se the problem users, but this isn't that much a problem, because one can just avoid an annoying user, which isn't the case on your own question.

Comment: So you don't like me, and you can block my every answer on a question of yours? How does that benefit the *community* reading those answers?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I imagine it would work, if the "blocked user" wouldn't be able to open any questions of the user who blocked him. So he cannot annoy the questioner anymore, but let's say leave the old answers of that person there. I don't see the disadvantage here, because if one user less can answer the question, it makes really no difference

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'm not seeing how it benefits the community to not address a situation that warranted this much attention. I almost left StackExchange because of bad behavior from a large number of people, and quite honestly, don't much enjoy the experience at the moment.

Comment: @WayneEra Then someone who regularly post superficially seducing argument re: C++ but often misleading and contradictory info would be able to block me, and I wouldn't been able to debunk the misinformation ever again. Nice system.

Comment: What some ppl would consider "problem user" is what others would see as "good debunker of misinformation".

Answer (score 4):

> Administrators could review which users are the most often ignored,
>   which would be a strong indication that someone should be put in the
>   penalty box or even locked out of their account

That's an encouragement to

- ignore unpopular opinions or people who frequently refute your points
- hope these "annoying" people get banned.

**That's the most evil idea I have seen for a while.**

Answer (score 2):

I initially didn't like this idea, but after seeing [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11457/unfair-closing-of-a-question-on-superuser) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/why-was-my-brothers-so-account-conbined-to-mine) I really think that there is a possible need for this in the future. Stack Overflow and Server Fault are more focussed then Stack Overflow, and Stack Overflow is bound to attract a lot more hate than the other sites.

Any moderators on Stack Overflow will require hair on their teeth and all the forces of the [League of Justice](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/why-cant-you-have-just-one-site/)) combined.

*I realise there is a Greasemonkey script for this, however I don't use Firefox and work on any of 5 different machines at any given time, these are not working solutions for me*.

Comment: Eh? Those questions are from two different users.

Comment: "SO and SF are more focused then SO, and SO is bound to attract a lot more hate then the other sites."

Is that a typo? Which one of those is MSO?

Answer (score 2):

This would be a good idea, because, if users on SE don't want to be annoyed by certain other users, they should be allowed to do so, conveniently.

I'd also say that if a certain user gets ignored by too many users, we could put his account in suspension.... that's up to the moderators, but it might be a good idea as that particular user is not doing any good towards SE, and only annoys others.

Comment: I don't like the idea of the automatic suspension, it would be prone to abuse.  A better thing to do in that case would be to have an automatic flag on the person so a mod could take any action if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to revisit this question here [Can we have a feature to ignore specific user's pings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277144/can-we-have-a-feature-to-ignore-specific-users-pings).

The argument that Stack Exchange is no a social network is used to refuse this feature.

To an extend there is a degree of socialising in the SE sites, comments, chat rooms and meta. Regular users do develop online relationships to varying degrees.

Sometimes people just don't get along.

Sometimes may receive pings from a user that they find annoying, where there is no objective reason to flag those pinged comments.

We all have our good days and bad days.

Sometimes it would be helpful to mute a users pings. It may reduce flags, and it may reduce tensions.

If the feature is in chat, it makes sense to include this feature for the site. It would reduce noise. And as in chat, the user can be un-ignored, so it's not doing anything irreversible.

Answer (score 2):

If this is implemented (and I am personally in favour of it), I think there needs to be some granularity. You should be able to choose which combination of questions, answers, and comments from a particular user you will not see (or be notified about)—and perhaps even be able to choose to not see only comments from a particular user in response to your *own* questions or answers.

I think there is a difference between something being reported as offensive in an objective sense (where a flag is appropriate), and just encountering somebody who keeps responding to you in a way that you find tiring.

Certain personalities just "clash," and, over time, there is a pattern of personal dispute. When it comes to comments, continuing to air such a fundamental difference of opinion serves no purpose. (Comments are not normally the forum for an ongoing debate.)

Rather than continuing to try to just ignore all comments from a particular user, it could be beneficial to simply never see them.

Not seeing questions and answers could address a similar situation.

The argument that not seeing a particular question could cause you to post a duplicate is valid—but questions get marked as duplicates all the time, even those that are visible to everyone. I doubt that there would be any significant increase in the need to mark questions as duplicates just because some users decided to turn on this option for certain other users' questions.

I don't see posting the same answer as somebody else a problem. This happens too—because nobody frames their answer in the same way. General voting simply decides which answer is framed in the best received way.

I can't really see a downside to this, but I can see an upside. (At least for some people in some situations.)

Answer (score 2):

Considering the never ending pronoun wars going on right now, I can imagine this feature being used to pre-ignore people or the moment someone mentions their pronouns, immediately getting ignored.

Not that it would be a new thing since pre-blocking or getting blocked the moment you reveal your pronouns is done on other sites too. Even though it will not really make those users feel unsafe, it might them feel like they are being shut out and censored.

And since I am against any kind of censorship be it indirect or direct, this might not be the best idea. But still, that is a side effect of adding a ignoring/blocking function on any site regardless and it might be useful for some people. Personally I rarely use those functions.

Answer (score 2):

**Suggestion: Rather than blocking an entire user's question/answer/comments, just stop answers/comments from a certain question showing up in our notifications**

From my experience, the biggest problems with harrassement come from the comments on various questions and answers. I have seen several offensive comments directed at me during my time at SE. I *want* to ignore these users and just move on. I don't want to silence them or prevent them from contributing. They can say whatever they want, I just want to not have to sit there listening to them. However, it is really difficult to do so when they keep spamming comments directed at you and I have to keep looking at their harassing comments (which are often just polite enough to avoid being flag-worthy) every time I open my inbox.

To put it another way, the current environment is basically set up to force people to repeatedly expose themselves to harrassing feedback over and over again, and then claim that not wanting to see this harrassment is a failure of the individual not being "mature enough" to ignore it (which comes off as victim blaming) when the system itself is tailored to prevent the individual from taking action to get away from the harrasser. Flagged material can be removed by moderators but this depends heavily on subjective decisions by mods as to what they consider to be crossing a line. It does nothing to break the cycle of aggression. Being forced to read every harrassing comment in order to make the notification go away and then see it floating around my inbox afterwards makes it really tempting to escalate things in a knee-jerk defense and really hard to just "ignore it and move on". The comments floating around the inbox mean you get repeatedly aggrivated rather than it being a one-time thing. It's kind of like being in an office setting and being mandated to have nasty e-mails pinned to the wall of your cubicle every time you go to work. The only way to avoid the comments is to not go on SE, which is kind of counterproductive.

My suggestion, just have subsequent answers and comments not show up in notifications if the user so chooses. I probably wouldn't even notice that these harrassing comments had been made if it wasn't for them showing up every time in my inbox. By default notifications could always be on and have to be removed on a by question or by comment chain basis by the user. This would make it much easier to just "ignore it and move on". Questions themselves aren't that big of a deal because unless they're blatantly off-topic like "why user X sucks" (and likely to get deleted anyway as a result) the asker is generally focused on their own question rather than harrassing another person.

Again, I don't care that people say these harrassing things, I just care that I'm forced to look at it. Reading the comments of this question, this seems to be similar to what other people are trying to articulate they want as well.

This way you have the best of both worlds. You dramatically cut down on flamebait (as well as stop many of these exceedingly long, unhelpful comment chain arguments that many SEs frown on) but at the same time you are not directly silencing any one individual. All of the harrassing user's questions, answers, and comments would still be there, so there is no risk of duplicating answers (they are still visible to the ignoring user if they go to directly look) or ignoring information based on its source. Any outright inappropriate response can still get flagged. If someone wants to ignore the responses to their own question, well, they're shooting themselves in the foot for why they wanted to ask a question on SE in the first place. And I'm sure some people would like to no longer be notified about an old question they no longer have interest in.

Comment: While I might support such a feature, it's very far fetched as an answer here. It's not in any way ignoring a user.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance But it does reduce exposure to harrassing comments without outright silencing a user or invoking the mods, which a lot of people here seem to be concerned about with any "ignore" feature.

Comment: Still, the main point of ignoring a user is to block **all** their posts/comments from showing anywhere for you, without the need to go post after post. At least that's how I see it.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistancing It might work if you set it up to ignore notifications from a particular user, instead of a particular answer or comment chain.

Answer (score 1):

Now we have the [Official FAQ on gender pronouns and Code of Conduct changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes) this would actually be a useful feature to prevent mods having to clean up too many gender pronoun comment threads.

This is an old feature request, and it gets requested every now and again, and would save a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should **never** hide any questions/answers or comments from other people.

But what could be interesting is a specific highlighting for the question/answer/comment.

This has the advantage that you could still see everything but if a comment of your "ignore" list is set you know to ignore it because otherwise you will ending in a discussion.

On the other hand, you can see it also fast and for some particular reason you never want to answer that user, you see it fast **but** you still see it and you still can answer them if you find the question good enough to answer.

I do agree that it's the content of the question matter in stead of the user but we are all human and almost everybody have some person they really don't like.

If this update ever comes, I also should implement a tool where consistent downvoting of ignore list is checked.
It's not because **you** want to ignore a specific person, that the person should be punished by you.

Answer (score -3):

It is important that victims of abusive behaviour aren't the ones who have to expend the emotional labour to deal with it.

The current stance of the moderators / owners is almost akin to "victim blaming".

Simply asking people to "ignore" bad users and downvotes is wrong.

Even if a client-side script was used to block users from view, the negative effects of their downvotes are still in place.

A block function needs include preventing comments, visibility and downvotes.

Comment: How is the existence of the rude/abusive and unfriendly/unkind flags you can flag a post with  "victim blaming"?  If you see that behavior, flag it and if it is legitimate, the user in question will either get a warning or get suspended.

Comment: @Daedalus - that process doesn't seem to work . Because it depends on the judgement of the moderators, who sadly have shown over time that they are happy to tolerate behaviour which others consider sufficiently bad to drive users away.

Comment: Your **answer** got 3 down votes(at the time of this comment).  As this is meta, they likely disagree with your premise that SE is victim blaming.  Moreover, that process does work; I've seen it happen with many flags I've made.