# Is it possible to block a user?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users)

There is a user on SO that is young and act very immature, they take the whole point thing way to far and live on SO just to gain points.  Here lately I post some very well defined and legit questions about some concepts I am learning and trying to understand better and this person will go out of there way to post negative comments about me posting questions.  An example is last week I had a question in regards to performance of loading different kinds of files for settings, like ini, json, xml files and then today I posted a question in regards to the performance of accessing an array of setting once it is returned from one of these files and the kid is non stop complaining about me "posting the same question over and over again" when in reality the questions are completely non related to each other and just bashing me.  I have been very polite to him in my comments back and tonight someone down voted him so he starts bashing me that I down voted him and it's just getting really annoying as it is happening more and more often with this user.

So I am just asking, is there an option to block my post showing up to certain users?  If this is not an option I think it would be a really good idea!

Comment: @Anders actually is was deleted by automated process as it got negative score and no answers. Anyway I'll flag this in order for proper closure as duplicate..

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd OK, thanks. I just noted that it linked to a "removed for moderation purposes", didn't think of the automatic process.

Comment: @Anders no problem, without privilege to see deleted posts you can't really know. :)

Answer (score 7):

With regards to your concerns, if you think a user is unfairly targeting you, then your best bet is to flag a comment that you think is inappropriate and let a moderator know why.

**It's not a good idea to retaliate. It just weakens your case.**

Caveat:

If you're posting questions that are quite broad or open ended (as performance questions necessarily are if you don't have a specific set of constraints in mind), then you're going to raise the ire of that part of the community that thinks you're just asking open-ended questions to gain reputation, instead of actually looking for an answer to a specific problem you have.

The community as a whole (well, the 'older members') tend to look down upon people who are using the reputation system as a game, instead of answering specific questions for specific problems.

**Edit**: After taking a look at your Stack Overflow [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143030/jasondavis), it does seem like you ask broad, open-ended question on a wide variety of topics, combine that with your ratio and that's a possible indicator of why this particular user targeted you.

I'm not saying it's right, but it is a plausible explanation.