# Unwanted answer-person

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to block a user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36989/is-it-possible-to-block-a-user)

I have gotten two answers from the same person. Each turned out to be a wild goose chase, although he answers as though he knows the answer will work. Now he has replied to a third question with a comment that says it is the same question I asked before (it isn't), and that he answered the previous question (he didn't really). He is asking me to explain myself.

I would prefer that he not attempt to answer my questions. I do not want to take him to task in the public comments section. Is there anything I can do? Grin and bear it?

Comment: What you said. Grin and bear it. We can't block other users.

Comment: Grin and bear it. Vote down answers that are plainly wrong. Let the community do the rest.

Comment: @Lucifer: No, [How to shrink wrap image in wxScrolledWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13025164) and [Scrollbars half way off screen when wxFrame is maximized](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13065763)

Comment: @Lucifer No, but I would prefer that the question and the answer-person remain anonymous. I do not want to embarrass him.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it has only one answer, i think another one is deleted one, so i can't see it

Comment: Well, the down-votes are coming in. Grin-and-bear-it it is then.

Comment: @Lucifer: No, there are no deleted answers. There is, however, a 3rd question that the other person answered: [Bands of background color show when painting image as it is uncovered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877307/12877493#12877493)

Comment: FWIW, the "Scrollbars half way" and "Bands of background" both turned out to be bugs in wxWidgets.

Comment: To be clear: None of his answers are (to my untrained, novice eyes) blatantly wrong, and knowing that you hit obscure bugs is perhaps a bit too much to ask. Still, him requiring you respond to get more answers is not constructive. You could flag such a remark, but most of all you move on and not take it personally.

Comment: As for the downvotes, see the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. People are most likely saying something like: "I disagree that there is anything to be upset about here or worthy of discussion on MSO" by downvoting.

Comment: Aye. [Grin 'n bear it](http://i.imgur.com/6CrPD.jpg).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I decided just to delete the one about the clipped sliders. It is so bizarre that I doubt if anyone else will be bitten by it. The writer of the BoxSizer code quite understandably did not know about a kluge that Windows uses to remove the border when a window is maximized. There are workarounds in the wx code for that misunderstanding which work for the normal paths through the labyrinth, but of course I took the one less traveled by. I am going to inform the wx developers. I suspect they will set it all straight.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Grin and bear it. Every user is allowed to contribute answers. To show that an answer is incorrect or unhelpful, it can be downvoted.

Should this particular user go about and give enough particularly bad answers, at some point an automatic post-ban might kick in, preventing him from submitting more answers. But that will only happen in an extreme case. (And if I'm looking at the correct user in your questions, it seems unlikely this will happen)

There is nothing more that can or should be done. If you don't want to spend time on this particular user, don't spend the time. It's as simple as that.

Comment: I've always wondered how to deal with a user who constantly posts with strange, almost nauseating formatting, yet gains votes and accepts with very few people editing them into shape. If you hang around the [css] tag for a while, you'll spot him.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I usually obsessively stalk them, find out where they live and hunt them down....but I've been informed that I should not recommend such practice. Glad I'm not part of the CSS tag...

Comment: Speaking of which, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152540/dealing-with-misguided-reviewers-take-2#comment438393_152540

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: I know what you speak of. There's at least one such user in the [java] tag.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Ouch, that almost makes me want to be more active in the review queues again to stop that from happening. But then again it's acceptances like that one which have made me stop almost completely

Comment: Whoops, totally misread your last reply. You're referring to my linked comment, right?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Yep, was referring to the link in the linked comment.