# Deleted comments persist in the global inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

A comment directed to popular demand, posted and deleted in my question about high rep users is still in my and popular demands' global inbox.

Additionally, edits do not affect the global inbox.

Comment: Was it my comment? I bet it was my comment. That wasn't supposed to be said. Now it's out. Aw, fishtail...

Comment: @Grace, not sure if you're kidding, but the comment in question was from @badp to me.

Comment: @Popular If neither of you saw it, then I have nothing to worry about! It's a secret to everybody.

Comment: @Grace I have it saved, but I'm sure we can work out a way to keep it out of the public eye. Let's say....5000 reputation, on non-sequential post IDs

Comment: I was about to open the same bug report. Someone deleted a comment, it was correctly removed from the *Responses* tab in recent activity page, but not from the global inbox.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Deletions are now reflected* in the inbox.

There is, of course, a natural race condition; wherein you load a page with a notice right before the originating user deletes the answer/comment.  That's not going to be addressed.

As for edits, we're unlikely to ever reflect those in the inbox.  Its a lot of trouble (technically), when you're almost always just going to go and read the post/comment.

<sub>*This is "going forward," old items that are in the inbox that correspond to deleted posts or comments will remain.  At least for the time being.</sub>

Comment: Has this regressed? I have had a deleted comment at the top of my global inbox for a few hours now. it says there is a new comment on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353, but I don't see it there. it says the comment was made 3 hours ago, so i don't think this is exempted under your "going forward" disclaimer

Comment: @Kip - ah, that's a bug with loading an inbox once its been flushed due to inactivity.  That particular comment has, in fact, been *persisted* as deleted.  I've pushed a fix out, and the next time your inbox is loaded from the persistent store (which is... kind of indeterminate, but it'll happen eventually) it should be fixed.  Thanks for reporting that!

Comment: Was that fix specific to Kip's issue?  Because I've had continuing issues for the last hour:  a comment to one of my answers was deleted and each time a new comment was posted in reply to that answer, the deleted comment showed up as the "new" comment in the inbox.

Comment: @James - I've bounced your inbox (forced it to be reloaded).  This can take a few minutes.  Let me know if your inbox items are corrected when it comes back (note, new items should appear immediately).  Note that the new item count, and the seen/unseen highlighting are lost when an inbox is "bounced."

Comment: The inbox looks correct now.  (I wasn't meaning to complain that _my_ inbox wasn't working; I just wanted to make sure, if it was a bug, that you knew).

Comment: @James - it'll be fixed for everyone... eventually.  Not visiting any SE-site for about 12 hours should do it.  But for you, extra-special *right-now service*.  Thanks for confirming the fix, that lets me know it isn't some other - more subtle - bug.

Comment: *"Not visiting any SE-site for about 12 hours"* I see a problem here... I only sleep for 8 hours.

Comment: The issue seems to have returned :(

Comment: I confirm @badp. I sometimes get those zombie comments in my inbox.

Comment: ...and it's back.

Comment: and still back.

Comment: Yup, still back.

Answer (score 4):

Update 2011-02-20 — This seems to have been fixed again?
Update 2011-03-26 — No, not fixed.
Update 2011-05-04 — Ah, [Grace explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89829/do-deleted-replies-still-show-up-in-the-inbox-anyway/89831#89831) that only deleted comments to posts *that you own* persist in the Inbox.

---

<s>Indeed, this annoyance has been back for some time.</s> Some examples, just in case it helps:

1. My Inbox shows deleted comments, when I already read them in [the post](https://superuser.com/questions/17188/greyed-out-emails-in-mail-app/17281#17281) before they were deleted (old example, not currently shown):

   [image: Deleted comment, which I already read]
2. ... and also when I did *not* read them in the [linked post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77360/i-have-grown-disappointed-with-stack-overflow) before they were gone (comment 190060):

   [image: Deleted comment, which I never read]
3. When a comment [has been edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78078/possible-bug-in-comment-replies-with-trailing-dots), it shows the old summary text (comment 190271; update: this [is by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66766/global-inbox-message-not-updated-after-comment-edit)):

   [image: Edited text]
   [image: Summary in Inbox]
4. Same texts in [meta.stackoverflow.com/inbox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/inbox), but I guess that's the source for some Ajax magic that populates the actual Inbox.

Comment: an interesting observation: The only comment of you persisting in my inbox is "(I have removed the link, by the way, @Hendrik)". Where are the others? (And was it the first one - do you remember?)

Comment: @Hendrik, sorry, more than 2 years have passed since you asked: I don't remember ;-)