# Duplicate Entries in Inbox?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, global-inbox

Really like the new inbox feature.

This is a bit of a nit, and it might have already been fixed in the nightly build, but some entries are duplicated, and I believe they are duplicated due to comment votes:

[image]

The original comment:

[image]

The original post: [How do you call this binary data type, and how to handle it in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782889/how-do-you-call-this-binary-data-type-and-how-to-handle-it-in-c/3782913#3782913)

Comment: that user chose to delete and resubmit the comment several times instead of clicking edit, when they were well within the 5 minute comment edit window..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, bear with me, this is not a bug... strictly speaking.

You *actually* had 4 comments on that post directed at you, however, after each of the first 3 the poster deleted the comment and revised his original text before re-posting it.

This looks so bad because we only show the first 50 characters of the comment (or answer), and each comment started with the same 50 characters in this case.

This is related to this [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox) (more of a feature-request really), which we'll probably address sometime this weekend.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing.  Thank you for the explanation, and I hope that the issue will be addressed.