# Global inbox message not updated after comment edit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comment-replies, global-inbox

At the moment, I have the latest notification in the global inbox, content of which does not correspond either to the comment itself or the copy of it on "recent responses" page. This seems like the comment was edited and the updated version was not copied to the global inbox.

[image: screenshot]

ETA: OK, now this looks more coherent.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: just testing :) @Tobias: see the edit.

Comment: @Tobias: now tell me what is in your inbox? "just edit :)" in the previous comment was added after the edit.

Comment: I *think* I saw what you mean, but your second comment overwrote the inbox contents again. Can you post & edit another comment please?

Comment: @Tobias. hm, that's interesting.

Comment: ok, confirmed .

Comment: are deleted comment replies no longer stored in the envelope? only my inbox shows `@Tobias: threaded comments? Is that a` and ends there. The answer is [balpha's greasemonkey script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43055/146482) btw

Comment: @Tobias: I don't think they ever were. Yeah, I've also found his nick-highlighting script.

Comment: It also seems that after question renaming new replies are grouped as separately.

Comment: Totally as an aside, as for your screenshot: [JPEG ONLY!!! NO THINKING REQUIRED!!](http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/) ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The inbox shows only a summary of any item in it, and that summary is determined when the item is placed in the inbox.

Reflecting edits is very low priority as A)  they're rare, B) you'll almost always click through and read the item anyway.