# Comments in inbox do not show latest edits

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Global inbox message not updated after comment edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66766/global-inbox-message-not-updated-after-comment-edit)

This is a minor glitch, but comments in the inbox do not reflect latest edits. That is, if someone posts an @ message to me (in comments), and then edits it, my inbox will show the original unedited message.

See screenshot for details:

[image]

[image]

Comment: To view: right-click and select **Open image in a new tab** (If you are using a browser that works).

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox or just middle click the image now. :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd :)

Comment: To view: crop images appropriately and prevent people having to navigate.

Comment: I believe the system also shows you deleted comments; what you get in your inbox is sent once, when the comment is first posted.

Comment: @BenBrocka That was changed.  Now the only deleted comments it shows you are comments by moderators on posts of yours that they deleted.