# Incorrect number of comments shown on StackExchange drop down

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, global-inbox

Hi I've just seen the following situation. The drop down on the stackExchange on the upper left of my browser screen shows 4 comments on a question that only has two.

[image: shows 4 comments only has 2]

Is this a bug?

Comment: It *was* a bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox

Comment: Its still shows in my inbox. Also later comments on that question appear also. That question was asked today. As was this one obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible if authors delete their comments, too.

Answer (score 4):

We now sync these things up, the counts should be correct.