# Inbox shows deleted answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, global-inbox

This seems to be something that [keeps coming up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox) meta however as I have the issue now and all the other tickets on here are marked as complete I thought I would raise it again.

[image]

The question is id [6593672](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593672/how-to-encoding-the-self-link-when-there-is-a-querystring-in-an-rss-feed/6593707#6593707).

Answer (score 2):

[Quote:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox/65792#65792)

> Deletions are now reflected* in the inbox.
>
> There is, of course, a natural race condition; wherein you load a page with a notice right before the originating user deletes the answer/comment. That's not going to be addressed.
>
> As for edits, we're unlikely to every reflect those in the inbox. Its a lot of trouble (technically), when you're almost always just going to go and read the post/comment.
>
> <sub>*This is "going forward," old items that are in the inbox that correspond to deleted posts or comments will remain. At least for the time being.</sub>

Comment: I had read this, however it still shows in the inbox many hours after and with refresh I understand the race condition would only happen if it shows in the list before it is deleted and I had not refreshed.

Comment: Unless I have mistaken the meaning, it does actually say: "old items that are in the inbox that correspond to deleted posts or comments will remain."

Comment: Because that was prefixed with going forward I though that "old" referred to the time before the answer/fix was applied. I could be wrong though

Comment: I don't know... makes some sense.