# Deleted comments are persisting in the global inbox

Tags: bug, comments, global-inbox

I realise that there is other questions out there about the [below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox/65792) (First open one I found is [Deleted comments persist in the global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox/65792#65792)), but this is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

I often get the below issue where it will notify me about comments on my [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/485605) (in this case what appears to be the user re-writing after deleting their comment) that no longer exist.

Also, occasionally, I see comment snippets with text that doesn't match what is on the page when I view it.

Let me know if I should be trying to edit that one to remove the tag indicating that it has been fixed, and add the above as another answer.

[image]

Comment: There are no deleted comments on that question...what I see on the question matches what's in your screenshot.  Can you give a concrete example of this happening?...nothing seems out of place here.

Comment: I don't have any evidence (concrete our otherwise) beyond what is in this question, as by the time I realised there weren't two new comments (I use the global inbox to access comments/answers almost exclusively) it was obviously no longer highlighted. It would seem to make sense to me though that if I say that I know I accessed the first comment via the global inbox, and provided a reply at this time, and the other user subsequently replied once, that having 2 comments listed as a new in the global inbox isn't possible (Though acknowledge what your saying about the lack of deleted questions).

Comment: Actually - Could this "2 comments on" notification actually be a concatenation of the last read one and the new one. If so, and you want to stick with the current concatenation idea (Not bad fundamentally i.m.o) __PLEASE__ get the code to display "x comments __(1 new)__ to ....."

Comment: @Nick I just added [steps to reproduce](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207988/152859) please take a look. (it might be by design)

Answer (score 6):

Steps to reproduce:

1. User, let's refer to him as Joe, posts a comment on my post. (or @-replying)
2. I see the live update showing new item and open the inbox. Comment from Joe is there.
3. Joe deletes his comment.

That's it... the comment will live forever in my inbox.