# Meta Tag markdown with same colour as actual tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, markdown, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some markup to post tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags)

In [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166109/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox-not-fixed) question was the first time I have had occasion to use the [tag:status-completed] ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)), but was slightly disappointed to not see it properly represented (With a red background).

Does anyone else think this would be a nice feature for the devs to get around to implementing?

Comment: Don't think so animuson. This is about the colouring of the tag, that as I agree with [Tim Stone](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235) is my [fault](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166111/203560)

Comment: That question perfectly identifies both ways of writing tags, and is the original feature request that got tag syntax implemented.

Comment: Didn't read the answers.... The accepted answer does address what my question is about; The question isn't the same as here. That OP is wondering about tags in general, I was aware of the ability to make tags look like themselves, but not (and was asking about) how to accurately represent meta tags. If I was searching for my problem, certainly wouldn't be looking at how to use markdown to format tags, as I already know how to do this on every site except meta.

Comment: Your question is not different enough to warrant remaining open. It better serves as a signpost to that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax was a bit off and you created a link pointing to a tag called "status-completed" on Stack Overflow. What you wanted was `[meta-tag:status-completed]`, which renders as desired:

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I edited your original question accordingly.

Comment: Tim didn't find a duplicate? :o

Comment: Thanks [Tim Stone](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235) for correcting me and my question!