# Strange character appear in the notification

Tags: bug, comments, notifications

I have been notified of a comment left for an answer of mine. In the notification, I see a character that doesn't appear in [the comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/428/differences-between-hatred-and-hate/440#comment1553_440).

[image: screenshot]

The comment's text is the following one:

```
hate can be used as a noun? So I could say `my hate`?
```

Comment: The comment was edited, the notification always show only the first revision and I fear we don't have any "comment revision history". :/

Comment: How didn't I notice that? I was sure I didn't see the "pencil" icon when I looked the comment. Sigh! I need to stop asking question, and count until 100 before asking any new question.

Comment: I thought the notification would show the comment as it currently appears, though.

Comment: Nope, as far as I know and it also makes sense the comment text is copied as is and added as notification. It's not a "pointer/reference" to the actual live comment. See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65792/152859): *As for edits, we're unlikely to ever reflect those in the inbox*

Comment: Strange, I was sure that, at least in one occasion, what I saw was the comment as edited, not the original one. It's time to eat more fish, or buy new eyeglasses. `;)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno we also know the inbox text is a copy from the fact that a comment can be entered and then deleted and *still* appear in the @ target's inbox

Comment: @AakashM That is a good point. Still, I know I didn't get a notification about a comment simply for the fact the post for which the comment was posted has been deleted. That is because who wrote the comment was not a moderator; if the comment comes from a moderator, the notification is always given, even when the post is deleted.

Comment: Well, maybe the comment author edited it to add the @kiamlaluno so you saw the edited version.