# Clicking on inbox message regarding subsequently deleted comment brings user to page with broken top bar

Tags: bug, user-interface, global-inbox, top-bar, achievements-dialog

*This particular case is minor and perhaps unworthy of note, but I suspect it applies to a larger pattern (e.g. **all** "phantom" inbox messages, or perhaps even the general case of broken internal links).*

I received an inbox message notifying me of a comment,

[image]

which was subsequently deleted. (There's [a separate thread about deleted comments persisting in the inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox)—an issue whose fix appears to have regressed.)

Clicking the inbox message brings me to the appropriate page, except none of the top bar's dropdown menus appear to be functioning. The <kbd>StackExchange</kbd> button links to SE's home page, while the inbox and achievements buttons appear to have lost their "click" event handlers (and therefore don't respond). On the left, the missing event handler; on the right, the normal case:

[image]