# We need a mechanism for 'purging' seen inbox messages

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox

There are certain situations where a message is better off not being seen. Things that are upsetting, rude, or offensive for certain, or one might want to housekeep their inbox.

[Dopplegreener's post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371410/please-clear-chat-message-notifications-out-of-my-inbox-if-the-message-was-delet)  gives an example where this would be useful in chat, with a rude message that was deleted turning up in the inbox, and here's an [example of it being useful in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349779/deleted-comments-on-followed-posts-persist-in-the-global-inbox/359719#359719), where a seen inbox entry isn't purged.

So *in general* some kind of mechanism for this would be useful across the public platform components. There's a suggestion we can request the latter as its own question, but this seems an inbox-level, not chat/qa-level issue.

Implementation obviously should be up to y'all, but a minimum viable option would be something global to a post or chat message, and the ideal would be per user being able to set what they don't want to see.

I'm not sure if the inbox is generated dynamically or managed separately, but being able to mark content as something not to turn up in the inbox might be a useful feature.

Comment: Where you want this to be able to be done by mods / room owners? Or automatically when a comment is red flag deleted?

Comment: I'd say it depends on the type of content - I'd say automatic for red flagged posts, but where appropriate having an explicit option

Comment: A related (more generally useful) feature request from [12 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/282094) was recently updated to deferred. --- Your request seems to be text based (from anyone), but that can be successfully flagged; which ought to result in it being removed (it always works for me). The one in the link in this comment is user based, so they can't sneak in something that can't be flagged successfully; plus it has way more votes than you can hope for in the next few months.

Comment: "We're going to take a look, and there will be a separate (2018 version) discussion once we've got some ideas."  This is an idea. Its more targetted, about content not people... seems in line to how we always do things.

Comment: [Yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371414/we-need-a-mechanism-for-purging-seen-inbox-messages?noredirect=1#comment1239782_371414), and that's why it hasn't worked. The comments (at that link) on the question reiterate that, why two solutions tackling each part of the problem is better than one size fits all and misses nothing.