# Inbox improvements: providing more control over what appears in the dropdown list

Tags: discussion, notifications, global-inbox

<sup>*In a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382693/inbox-improvements-marking-notifications-as-read-unread-and-a-filtered-inbox-v/382801?noredirect=1#comment1277571_382801) response to my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382801/15168) to the question [Inbox improvements: marking notifications as read/unread and a filtered inbox view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382693/15168), staff member [marrados](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1221265/marrados) asked me to create a new question.  Here is the new question.*</sup>

With the modifications outlined in [Inbox improvements: marking notifications as read/unread and a filtered inbox view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382693/15168), I'd like to see a way to get rid of (not show) notifications that I don't want to see anymore, and maybe a way to keep (show) notifications that I do want to see in the dropdown list, for perhaps a month or so.  AFAIAC, it would be more important to remove notifications that no longer interest me than to keep ones that do.

For example, my dropdown inbox currently looks like this:

[image: Top of my inbox]

---

[image: Bottom of my inbox]

On the 'top of inbox' image, I really don't need the "sorry about that" comment to show up — I'd like to be able to mark it as "do not show".  Similarly with the "initialize it to what?", "thanks — that solved it" and the "thank you for the feedback" comments in the RHS or lower image.

As [41686d6564 stands w. Palestine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/348196/41686d6564-stands-w-palestine) [points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383087/inbox-improvements-providing-more-control-over-what-appears-in-the-dropdown-lis#comment1277653_383087), this is closely related to a prior question:

- [We need a mechanism for purging seen inbox messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371414/we-need-a-mechanism-for-purging-seen-inbox-messages)

I see that notifications are kept forever — if I scroll down to the bottom of the drop-down (the last shown notification shown for me today is from 8th October), then the 'show all notifications' link opens up a tab with (for me) 1617 pages of notifications dating back to September 2008.  I'd still want all notifications to show up in this list so that the record is complete.

However, it would be helpful if the list of all notifications could be searched — by date range, tags, user ID, as well as the content of the notification. Similar comments apply to searching through comments I've made, though the user ID would be for the recipient of the comment rather than the sender. That gets tricky: for a comment on an answer, the comment could be addressed to another commentator, the answerer, or the OP of the question. Additionally, over time, some people change the name associated with their ID, but the message content doesn't change. Mapping user names becomes its own headache.

<sup>*Aside: when previewing the question, the images showed up side-by-side.  When reviewing and editing the question, they showed up one above the other.  I've now forced the images into a vertical stack with a horizontal rule between them, but why was there a difference between the preview and the final displayed information?*</sup>

Comment: The first part appears to be the same as (or similar to) [We need a mechanism for 'purging' seen inbox messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371414/348196).

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine — agreed.  I'll add to the question.  Thank you.