# Please remove comment notifications from the inbox if the comment was deleted as rude/abusive

Tags: feature-request, status-review, notifications, global-inbox, offensive

I recently got inbox notifications of rude/abusive troll comments from a post I followed. The comments were already deleted by the time I viewed the post from the inbox notification, but they are still showing up in my inbox:

[image: screenshot of undeleted rude/abusive comments]

I don't really need to be notified that someone commented:

> ugh ughguhgughguhgg uhgguhguhguhg ugh ughu gughughughug ughg uguh ughg frioooooooooooooooooo oooo...

Especially since the comments were already deleted.

<sup>(The comments in the above screenshot were from: [What is the difference between (these four) sleep states?](https://superuser.com/q/71835/10259))</sup>

According to an answer at the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) post, [Please clear chat message notifications out of my inbox if the message was deleted as rude/abusive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375326/162827):

> > So my suggestion: **If a message is deleted as rude/abusive in chat, any inbox notifications coming from its mentions should be deleted
> > too.**
>
> [image: Captain Picard says "and so it is done".]
>
> The change went live earlier this month. If you see any issues, please
> let us know.

I'm not sure if followed post inbox notifications are also intended to be included in the above feature. This meta post is either a bug report if the above feature is intended to also include followed post inbox notifications, or if not, this serves as a feature request to remove all notifications of comments that have been deleted as rude/abusive from the inbox.

Comment: And were they ever removed from email notifications of pending comments. See my comment on the quoted answer.

Comment: Related previous bug report (marked as [status-bydesign] at the time): [Deleted comments on followed posts persist in the global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349779/335251)

Comment: The request here is really the bare minimum. However, I really want to see *all* deleted answers/comments removed as per [Deleted comments on followed posts persist in the global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349779/323179) because not all rude comments are flagged with that particular reason.