# Allow users to remove notifications in their inbox

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox

[Deleted comments on followed posts persist in the global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349779/deleted-comments-on-followed-posts-persist-in-the-global-inbox) is marked as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - if you have already seen a notification, then it is never removed from the inbox. That *includes* if the notification is for a comment that has been removed for being rude. Or any other posts that is inappropriate. Or unwanted for any reason.

As a user, I would like to not be able to see rude and/or unwanted content remain forever in my inbox. If such notifications are to not be *automatically* removed, then at least I should be able to *manually* do it.

Comment: Would hiding them without actually removing them work for you?

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371414/we-need-a-mechanism-for-purging-seen-inbox-messages) - and there's a reference to an even older request in my comments

Comment: Well there's still hope, [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383440/please-remove-comment-notifications-from-the-inbox-if-the-comment-was-deleted-as) is still under review and not rejected. (yet.)

Comment: Would be nice if it was given a whole ui where you could decide what kinds of notifications you wanted, and whether or not you have to individually mark things read, etc.

Comment: @KevinB like [this request suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210480/why-doesnt-stack-exchange-have-a-notification-center-in-account-preferences-wit)?

Comment: @Mast I suppose it's acceptable. The point is not seeing them. I don't think it matters too much if they are "deleted" or "hidden". Right now there is no real way to not see them.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda the FR is something I support (apparently I've seen it before since I had already upvoted it when I opened the link). However, I don't want to only limit to flagged removals. One might also dislike notifications that technically do not cross over the CoC.

Comment: I keep accidentally following posts, and forgetting to remove them using the method that actually works (a bug where you have to go to your profile). One of these days I'm going to get seriously flooded by unwanted notifications from this so this suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

By all means, that would be a useful feature.

My two cents are a little mockup, of how I envision this:

[image: mockup of delete notification button]

Same UI/UX as in comments, it will appear when hovering over the notification, or when viewing on a mobile device the "Delete" will always be there. It will also show for each item in the [global inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox).