# Is it possible to add means to help recognizing other users?

Tags: feature-request

How about a feature to privately flag individual users? I think of something that allows users to mark other users with i.e. a green, yellow or red flag. Only the user that marked the other user himself will be able to see that flag next to the username of the other user. It's not as harsh as [ignoring other users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users), doesn't make comment references to them incomprehensible but still allows to just skip questions of certain users or to spot comments of users that might be more likely worth reading than that of others.

The problem I would like to solve with this is that many users have a username of the form *user1234567* and a generic avatar which makes it difficult to recognize them. On the other hand I find it difficult to recognize the users as comment authors due to the lack of the otherwise ubiquitous avatar image.

Of course it would be also nice if one could optionally add a few words to the flag if that is feasible.

Comment: Might be useful. But might also better be implemented as userscript (it's for personal use anyway).

Answer (score 4):

This has been requested before and is not a *bad* idea as such.

However, it would undermine what in my eyes is a key social aspect of Stack Overflow: When you have a run-in with somebody, it's most often impossible to stay angry with the person for longer than a day, because *you simply forget who they were.*

It's an important social mechanism of the site, partly responsible for the very peaceful tone around here. It would be lost if one could privately "tag" their fellow users.

Comment: +1, do you rely on people forgetting you? :)

Comment: @sixletter world peace through amnesia! Might be an idea worth exploring :)

Comment: Who are you, and why are you replying to me!

Comment: @six I *think* I replied to a comment of yours once, but I can't recall what it was about really. *(awkward silence)*