# Meta Stack Overflow is currently offline for maintenance? Am I Error Banned?

Tags: support, meta, downtime

I randomly see `[Meta] Stack Overflow is currently offline for maintenance` pages every once in a while, and they usually go away in like 30 seconds.

Am I  errorbanned or something? Or is there really random "routine" maintenance on Stack Overflow that lasts < 30s?

Comment: I'm fairly sure Jeff dissaproves of hell-banning and error-banning users, but if they were to do it I doubt they'd make it common knowledge

Comment: Yes you are. I am too. So is he. Ice cream? Ohhh Kay.

Comment: +1, everytime I see "An error occurred" when voting I wonder whether it is this :D

Comment: I propose that the next time someone asks a question about hellbanning, nobody answer :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NO NO NO .... we do not error ban anyone.

What you are seeing is artifacts of a meta deploy, we have a system for continuous deployment on SO and SE sites, but deploys to meta unfortunately still involve a minor outage.

Comment: Oh lol okay, just checking, thanks. :)

Comment: You would say that, wouldn't you? ;)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're using brain\*\*\*\* to write code... :P +1 I guess

Comment: Props to yoda: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93806/is-there-going-to-be-a-process-around-hellbanning/93818#93818

Comment: [Props to me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93806/is-there-going-to-be-a-process-around-hellbanning/93818#comment-236635). :P

Answer (score 1):

Typically the M/SO/SE sites flicker off due to a new build deploying. Most of the times it is fairly quick although you may get the "Offline" message.

If you look in the bottom right conder under the cc-wiki logo you'll see the build number, currently rev 2011.6.8.4 (date, then probably 4th build today).

Error banning is fairly harsh and evil and I don't think SE would stoop to using it.