# Is there a sort of 'invisibility' ban?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, ban

I've been asking a lot of questions on Stack Overflow and recently one of my questions was down voted 3 times, after which I voluntarily closed it. Since then though, my questions seem to be getting hardly any views and no answers (when normally they are answered within moments).

I'm not sure what seems to be causing this but I'm wondering if I'm in some sort of hell ban or sin bin. Does Stack implement such a thing?

Comment: Are you talking about [How do I get a form to destroy an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645494/how-do-i-get-a-form-to-destroy-an-object)? You *deleted* that question, so you can hardly expect activity there

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[From the SE employee Sam Saffron](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93806/is-there-going-to-be-a-process-around-hellbanning/93857#93857):

> Hellbanning, slowbanning, errorbanning, and randombanning are all
>   things we have never experimented with and do not intend to.

The visibility of your question and the number of responses you receive depend on a large number of factors. Make sure that your questions are clear and well written, you can also try to put a bounty on the question to get more attention.

The number of questions on SO also increased substantially in the last years, I don't know if there are any reliable statistics on it, but my subjective impression is that questions on SO get less views on average than a year ago.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't assume it's a feature, there is also the human element. If you ask a lot of bad questions then a couple of things may happen:

1. Some regular site visitors will remember you and may avoid your
   future questions
2. People who check your question history may choose to avoid you

Answer (score 4):

> recently one of my questions was down voted 3 times, after which I voluntarily closed it.

You can close your own questions, but that would require four other users who vote to close the question, or a moderator who votes to close it; in the latter case, the question would be closed immediately. You can delete them, if they don't have any answer with score higher than zero (which means the number of up-votes is higher than the number of down-votes).
In both the cases, the question cannot have new answers.

SE sites don't have bans that don't allow to see your question. If you don't get answer is probably because:

- You are asking something too specific, and nobody knows the answer.
- Your questions are not clear, and nobody is answering them. In this case I would expect comments about the questions, though.