# Since a few days maybe I see less answers and less views, is this normal?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, questions

Is it possible that since few days all questions get viewed less? And questions are getting less answered in total average on Stack Overflow, Ask Ubuntu etc?

Like before it was rapid at-least some feedback, but now its like lonelyness.

Is this normal? Can we see total average viewers by day or week as public, to know if our community is still strong and growing?

Can we see if our community has same traffic or if it is getting lower or higher? I mean its lonely when I ask and never get any feedback anymore.

I mean:

```
- Year
Jan/2012    Feb/2012   March/2012
--1%        ---3%      ----------------(overflow)

- Weekly
Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri
0%   0% 100% 20 30   40 50

- Hourly
00  01 02 ...... 24
%    %  %        %
```

Comment: Someone got [hellbanned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119615/176163).. ;)

Comment: http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com has some data for site traffic.

Comment: You've been a member for less than two months and have five questions. I'm not sure it's possible to have seen enough to guess at any overall trends from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably one of

1. You.
2. Statistical variation
3. A few days ago was a better time to ask questions:

[What is the best time to ask questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1313/172958)

Comment: Can we not see as public. How is our community? is it statistically growing or going to down like without knowing, maybe there is another community out there.

Comment: I mean its nice to see one community. But also nice to see if its going upwards or downwards.

Comment: At the moment, we have 968,295 registered users and it's only going up

Comment: Thank you. I am very happy that our community is growing. I wish it grows to unlimited and have lots of collaboration, solving missions together. :)