# Disgorging Clipboard Developers

Tags: discussion, question-quality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Help Vampire problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)

Is there some slightly more Machiavellian way (other than the community-based approach already implemented) to discourage the deluge of questions during certain hours that beg for basic code "examples"?

Full disclosure: I believe that software developers should be licensed like any other professional (laywer, doctor, architect, nurse, etc...).

Comment: "during certain hours"...?

Comment: From a guy sitting on the east coast of the US, it is obvious when the outsourced folks arrive at the office. I was trying to be politically correct.  Which I, typically, am not.

Comment: Stop people posting full code scripts as they salivate for the precious, precious EXP. When you feed it, the elastic jeans are only an order away

Comment: Ah, I know *exactly* what you mean, @jonny. Those So-Cal programmers stick out like a bunch of sore thumbs.

Comment: It's a good thing I don't work for you.  I have a master's degree, but no licenses of any kind, except my driver's license and my marriage license.

Comment: Programmers gonna program.

Comment: @Robert - I also hold a master's degree.  I work hard to hone my craft.  I think SO is an excellent resource.  I also know that not everybody gets to grow up to be a jedi.

Comment: @Shog: It's the shorts, sandals and sunscreen that give us away.  The only thing wrong with our code is that our code comments are occasionally punctuated with the word "dude."

Comment: @jonnyGold You probably didn't intend it, but this comes across a little like thinly-veiled xenophobia. Is your problem really that you don't like that people in different time zones who may or may not have degrees are programming and asking questions, or that you are just seeing too many poorly asked questions?

Comment: What's a clipboard developer and what UTC hours do they keep?

Comment: Well, you all managed to avoid my actual point.  Xenophobia has nothing to do with it.  I care not from whence one originates.  I care lots when one tries to live off the altruism of others.  Your points are well taken - I shant bring the subject up again.  Nor shall I answer many more questions.

Comment: Your actual point sounds like you're being racist

Comment: Elitist, yes. Unabashedly. Racist, no.

Comment: **"Clipboard Developers"** *::chortle::* FSM only know that there are a lot of these sorry specimens in the world, and most of them will probably never amount to anything, but it is not our business to sort them out. Close the bad content, then delete it and move on. If they're persistently bad enough they'll get question banned. And who knows, maybe they'll learn.

Comment: If you want to be Machiavellian, post an answer which doesn't work. That'll teach them fairly fast :)

Comment: @Benjol post an answer which doesn't work *and  show it  only to the OP*. Hell-answering, here we come!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find that 5  close votes followed by 3 delete votes works in the majority of these cases. I don't think anything else is necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry... did I piss on a sacred cow?  Or did I point at the elephant in the room?

Comment: @jonnyGold -- I don't think so; I just think the system here works well, and nothing more is needed.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure why you want to be more "Machiavellian" here, but no - employing duplicity and deception goes against everything Stack Overflow was built to accomplish. If you want poor quality to go away, down-vote it, improve it, close and delete it, and/or flag it. There are a wealth of tools at your disposal, you need only use them.

#### See also: [Is there going to be a process around hellbanning?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93806/is-there-going-to-be-a-process-around-hellbanning)