# Can I get my (ignored) question on SO answered when I don't have enough rep to offer a bounty?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

I am trying to get an answer to a [question I posted on Oct 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963610) - I only had one gentleman make some suggestions (which did not solve my issue), but that was it - no one else has answered or commented on the question, except for one up-vote for the question. I am confused why this happened - I don't think it's a bad question, but there could be many other reasons - I am trying to understand those reasons.

I added more info as and when I found something new that's relevant, and also updated the title to make it more relevant based on some suggestions on the meta, hoping the question would get noticed (I read that the questions will change order based on update time) - but so far it looks like the question didn't make it under anyone's radars OR raise anyone's interest.

I don't have enough reputation to offer a bounty - and that makes it even harder. Is there any other way to get someone to help me with this question? Or, am I apparently on an ignore-list (that is, if such a thing exists) for a mistake I did but didn't realize I shouldn't have done it (if that's the case, please help me understand what I did)?

Comment: Post it on social networks/Reddit/SD/etc (at your own peril, depending), use the "share" link on the bottom of your question.  In other words, promote, promote, promote.

Comment: I'm just inviting abuse for even suggesting this, but editing your question bumps it to the front page.

Comment: You're not on any "ignore list." On Stack Exchange sites, there's no such thing. The team has [rejected the use of hellbanning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93857/131713).

Comment: @PopularDemand We can't hellban you, but we can put you in the box for 15 (ish) years.

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses, @PopularDemand and all others. I didn't think my question was an exact duplicate to the one in subject since my question had some extra elements, but at least I got some comfort in knowing that I am not on a ban list :D although I wonder if my question deserved 3 down-votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bounties won't help. Bumping won't help. If a question like this didn't get an answer, it's because none of the regulars has an answer.

Roughly speaking, a situation like yours falls into one of two explanations. Either you've fallen into some fairly common trap, or you have some very localized problem, unique to you.

If it was the former, you'd have gotten answer.

Since you don't state that your problem can be reproduced by someone else by following some sequence of steps or another, no one else can possibly diagnose your local problem. So it's not surprising that you didn't get an answer.