# Upvote on answer undone

Tags: discussion, answers, up-votes, grace-period

I want to report something I have noticed. Twice today, I have given answers.

The first time, my answer was upvoted and I gained 10 reputation as always but within 5 minutes I noticed the 10 reputation gone. I went back to the answer and noticed I had 0 votes. I concluded that the upvote was undone.

The second time, I was upvoted and within 5 minutes the 10 reputation vanished and I went back to the answer and had 0 votes.

Is this just a coincidence or some kind of punishment for an offense?

Comment: Probably just a couple users that aren't quite sure.

Comment: oh.ok i thought i had commited an offence

Comment: It can't be a punishment as nothing can't be a punishment. Assume you never received those upvotes in the first place (you didn't according to the site now).

Comment: We don't punish by removing votes. We punish by banning.

Comment: @Cole More suspending, not banning

Comment: @Cole [They don't exist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93857/215468).

Comment: On mobile (but in desktop mode) I often misclick an upvote and then undo when clicking the score to get a break down; I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: A related (not duplicate) question I just posted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196519/problem-with-voting-ui-issue

Comment: @Cole You checked the link, right? *Hellbanning, slowbanning, errorbanning, and randombanning are all things we have never experimented with and do not intend to.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The system allows votes to be undone within 5 minutes after casting.  They can also be undone after an edit to the post.

This window is intentionally small to avoid people trying to game the system, but it exists at all because sometimes people make mistakes -- they read an answer, think it's good and upvote it, then read another that disagrees and realize they were wrong so they undo the vote.  Or they're just fickle.  Or clumsy.  Or using a phone and that voting arrow isn't what they were aiming for.  (I, like Richard Tingle in the comments, cast a lot of accidental votes on my phone and then have to undo them.)

If you do something that requires correction, you'll receive a comment (or an edit, or in an extreme case a message from a moderator).  Votes are not punitive.  And anyway, as noted in comments, removal of a vote isn't punishment in any case; it's not like you received a downvote.

Unless this happens a lot (two times is not a lot), it's best to assume somebody spazzed and just carry on.  It's not personal.