# Problem with voting (UI issue)

Tags: bug

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196513/upvote-on-answer-undone) got me to finally report this problem.

I've been noticing something odd with my up votes on SO and MSO.  I'd click on the up arrow and the vote count increases.  Then I click on the title link (to effectively refresh the page) or I'd come back to the question later and usually my up vote isn't evident (no highlighted up arrow and the vote count is off by 1).  It's as if I hand't voted at all.  I've found that I've been able to make my vote stick by upvoting a comment somewhere on the page before leaving the page.

Comment: I tested on this question, [meta-tag:status-norepro]

Comment: What browser are you running?

Comment: @Doorknob I'm running with Safari on a Mac OS.  You?

Comment: Win7 Chrome 29.0.1547.66

Comment: Any change [your vote ends up on a different post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175388/voting-counted-on-wrong-answer)? If so: Safari, and new/edited posts loaded using Ajax/WebSockets, and maybe the votes are even wrong *before* voting?

Comment: @Arjan it could very well be the same problem.  I just had not noticed.  How did you see that your vote for another question had changed?

Comment: I never had that problem, but the others simply saw the orange vote arrow on a different post after refreshing. As that always seemed to be a post *within the same question*, I guess that is something that you'd notice as well.