# I want to block some other user

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users)

Is it possible? blocking someone else.

Comment: What do you mean by "blocking"? Do you mean "Ignoring"?

Comment: You can try another internet.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman, yes, blocking, ignoring or something like that.

Comment: @Pekka, like the guy who insulted and then removed his comment at that question?

Comment: Look, why don't you try asking a bit more verbose questions instead? Then there wouldn't be a problem in the first place.

Comment: @ilhan that one comment about the intertubes in your SO question (I don't remember who the user was) was a bit snarky, yes. But the removal could have been because people flagged it as offensive - it wasn't necessarily removed by the user himself. And even if it was - people say things in the heat of battle they later regret, and remove. It has happened to me a lot of times. And it wasn't *totally* wrong either: If you already did some research, then *say so.* Otherwise people will think you are lazy. They have no way of seeing what you already did before asking the question.

Comment: Is this all because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840087/what-does-callable-typehint-mean) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839763/what-is-callable-typehint-in-php) questions?

Comment: @Damien yes, I think so.

Comment: I see, Pekka...Too bad I missed that comment though :). Anyway, @ilhan, you must admit that your last three/four questions, compared to the many others, are in great need of a revision. Blocking a user won't do any good: you might not get harsh comments, but the Community has better and kinder way to tell you something needs a correction, so if a question doesn't fit, it won't even if comments were disabled by design

Comment: @LarsTech, any you know?

Comment: This topic is about blocking/ignoring others. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users It has 75 upvotes and 9 favorites.

Comment: You seem fairly apt at ignoring others already. Why do you need a SO feature for it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Ignore" function on Stack Exchange (except on chat) and I don't think it is worth it