# Can we have a feature to ignore specific user's pings?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat, users, ping

This was asked 7 year ago

[Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users)

The sites have changed considerably over 7 years. What's on topic has changed, the nature of the internet has changed and there's sites in existence now that weren't then.

Can we please revisit it?

In chat we have a feature to ignore user everywhere, 
Can we have this feature so it extends to the SE sites network, or have it separately enabled from within the sites comments?

[image]

Comment: I *think* that the dupe closure is a clear sign that either you try to revive the old post by adding a reply there in hope to attract more views and hope someone will reconsider, or you can *waste* a bounty there trying to do the same. Anyway, the chat already has an ignore feature, and on the main site answers and questions should be "rated" by their content, not the person that posted them (I actually still stand for removing that information from the interface and see what happens). Comments are a different story, but problems with them should be handled with flags.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist yes it would be very interesting to remove the user information from posts, there would be perhaps, less biased voting? And I did add an answer the duplicate target.