# Please add option to mute a user or a post in the apps

Tags: feature-request, android-app, notifications, ios-app

I know of the old, [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) request to [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/270345). However, my request is specific to the apps.

A few days ago, I had this incident where a user repeatedly commented on one of my posts, whilst deleting previous comments (so other users would only see their latest, innocuous-looking comment). My phones (I have an Android phone (personal) and a work iPhone, both with the Stack Exchange app installed) kept buzzing every few minutes. Unlike on SO, mods aren't that active on the smaller sites, and my flag on that didn't get handled until hours later. I muted notifications for the SE apps in the meanwhile.

Now, comment notifications on the *sites*, I can easily ignore. After all, they do not affect anything outside of the browser tabs in which the sites are open. However, notifications on my phone are a different case altogether. I take them very seriously, and do my best to keep junk notifications to a minimum. That I enable notifications so that users whom I'm helping or who are helping me can communicate more efficiently with me  *does not mean* that I'm also permitting users on the site to harass me with notifications. And notifications that do affect the real world, like on the phone, can become harassment.

The apps should really have a feature to mute a user, or at least **mute a post**.

Comment: We'll take care of this. It's an easy client-side change to let you opt out of one specific post's notifications. I totally get the use. We'll add it (not immediately, but soon!) -- Really sorry you had to deal with that harassment.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi sure, thanks. (My sympathies about your situation, by the way)

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi: Thanks for noticing this. I saw it last night and was going to bring it to your attention as soon as the drama on MSO cooled down. I know it's been a rough couple of days for you, which makes it hard to work. In general, I don't like the idea of muting folks, but when a ping turns into buzz or noise in my pocket and when the number of pings can be artificially inflated, it sure seems useful to turn that off for awhile.

Comment: @JonEricson Technically you're not muting folks, just posts, and only from the mobile apps. That seems reasonable IMO.