# Reminders for [status-review] tags

Tags: feature-request, support

While the ability to set [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tags [helps the mod community to help bring up topics of interest to their respective communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca) (and in the context of meta, to try to triage matters of importance to the whole community that the Dev and Community teams might miss), stuff gets into the queue, and sometimes seems forgotten for over a year.

As someone who's helped direct and manage tickets - we often would set reminders for engineers should a client request follow up, which helped us keep track of things like that. It would be nice to have a similar, 'formal' mechanism to bump a question and let folks know 'this is an unresolved issue under review and it came up again'.

I would *hope* it's used sparingly of course, in the interest of removing items of interest to the community from the backlog.

I recently had a question I wanted to status review - and it so happened that the same question *had* previously been asked in 2019 *and* had a pending status review tag, which I had added in May 2020. The questions in question are besides the point - and I deem them to be a distraction. The main point is bringing attention to an unresolved issue in a less obtrusive but 'official' way that feeds into the back-end of running the network.

Could we have a way to add some sort of reminder flag to a question as mods to let the company know "Hi! This particular issue has been mouldering for years. Could we get some eyes on it?"

Comment: Alternative title: "We need a sharper stick with which to poke staff"

Comment: Naw, just a nice note, and a warm gift in the shoes.

Comment: Looking through the list of [tag:status-review] questions there are some going back 11 years. To be fair, some have been implemented but simply haven't had the tag updated. For example, the oldest request, from 2009: "[Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/282094)".

Comment: @Rob guess you're being sarcastic? This was never implemented.

Comment: @Sha, See: "[What are the similarities and differences between “irony” and “sarcasm”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/26624/246019)".

Comment: Maybe but current status tags *are* automatically added to jira so at the very least, there's an associated ticket to the question. At the very least it's more useful than a symbolic bounty

Comment: This feature should be added, some questions with [tag:status-review] are nearly 10 years old!(2013)

Answer (score 3):

I found this question while thinking the same thing myself, and wondered if the community might be interested in a review-queue-squash, in the style of a bug-squash? I'm envisioning we create a new question, where folks could review an individual item from the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) queue, and write an answer for any that should be removed from the queue. Reasons to do so could include:

- The requested feature/change has already been implemented
- The request is no longer applicable due to other changes on the site

Mods can then review those answers and remove the tag, where appropriate. This would pare down the list a bit, and perhaps spur the SE team to take a closer look.

Comment: It could also be an opportunity to highlight ones that are particularly in need of attention.  Having them in a new question could show evidence that the community _still_ cares, rather than that it's just accumulated votes over time.  It would also show it to people who may not have seen the original request.