# How should I deal with a stubborn, annoying user?

Tags: support, comments, off-topic

Long story short, out of the blue there appeared a user that seems determined in their attempts on derailing discussions I start on SE.

At first they were attempting to start comment wars and being unfriendly, I flagged everything they posted and most of it was removed.

Now they changed strategies, they just go there and try to call my attention or bring up something totally irrelevant to the context, always tagging me.

They appear to have no such interests related to other users.

As an aside note, they seem eager  eager to bring up stuff like (**real examples from them here**),

> "I put a .380 bullet through two rapists' necks"

and

> "menstrual blood has sometimes been referred to as unclean" (no one asked about menstrual blood)

and

> "you seem to condone rape"

and other stuff that seems somehow related with women's struggles. Rape, misoginy, *menstrual blood* and other stuff I just can't link to the questions they're posted on. To me it seems clear the only intent is goading me.

Also bear in mind that *I don't know who this person is or why they picked me*. I was just flagging all of their comments and also began ignoring them. As most of the earlier comments got removed, they now changed strategies and began to tag me on seemingly on-topic comments. Then they sidetrack and tag me, while bringing up  off-topic, often nonsensical or out of context comments..

To make things worse, the user has 15k+ reputation and idk if that's the reason, but mods seem not to agree the person has been determined to annoy me and often find a justification for not removing what they've been posting around. If I ignore them they'll just post 2/3 comments in a row, tagging me in them and ignoring everyone else in the comments.

The result is that they seem to have at least started on topic, so when I flag their off-topic comments, the mods don't remove them.

That includes an answer to a question I asked recently.

It was legitimate, it got many answers and upvotes, and they went there and posted an "answer" where they didn't respond to anything I asked and just overall tried to drag me into a fight, questioning the question, asking *why I posted it*, also challenged the *example I gave*, somehow telling I was wrong and overall trying to get a reaction from me. I didn't comment or answer anything, *since all of their deliberations were* ***completely off-topic*** and had an undertone of anger or flaming, with no apparent reason.

I flagged it as "not an answer", the mods declined to remove it on the basis that it was "okay to challenge a question's premise".

If it was an isolated case I'd agree, but seeing I reported like, 20+ comments from that person, most of them removed for violating the code of conduct, some being downright abusive, in that case I think mods should take action.

To be honest with the mods, I do think most of the rejected flags had a good justification on the outside, namely, the content seems okay. But considering the *other activity* from the same user, I think it is clear for the mods too that the intent of the comments is to cause annoyance.

I have made several nice contributions to stack SE but I seriously think SE is really lacking a block button or some other way of getting rid of these annoyances, and in case there's no solution to the problem, I'll just stop contributing.  I usually just ignore them, but one just has so much patience...

Comment: I would treat them the same as I would a troll:  Ignore 'em and flag 'em.  If they keep it up, why not flag them for a cool-down suspension?

Comment: @Ollie Yeah, the ignoring part is okay, the two main problems are:
1. Having to put up with it
2. Mods not removing stuff that's obviously crap and giving beautiful justifications for not doing so.

Comment: If moderators are not resolving an ongoing situation, you need to use the contact link at the bottom of the page for CM escalation. Include links to questions where these comments are/were posted, and any flags that were declined despite merit.

Comment: @Nij Yeah, that's about what I need. By the way, the comments that triggered my coming here were removed just a few minutes ago. Can the mods see it?

I really, really think the mods should take some more radical action, as I already posted on the community's meta, they answered me and all, but overall I just disagree I have to put up with this bullshit while mods do nothing.

Comment: You might also want to reduce the attack language in the post. Speculating over what a person does or is, only detracts from your position that you are a pure victim, and irrelevant meta commentary makes it harder to tell what is the actual problem versus what is your reaction to it. State the facts clearly, ask for a resolution to a particular problem.

Comment: @Nij Well, what you consider as "attack language", specifically?

Comment: @Nij by the way, I just could not help it. This is literally what the person is doing, so I might have a problem dissociating and writing a purely objective question.

Comment: The very first sentence, for one.

Comment: @Nij Okay, i'll edit all of those out.

Comment: EzequielBarbosa, see also this 11 year old feature request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/282094

Comment: Your emotional response is valid, of course, but intermingling it with the rational request for help here will only reduce the likelihood of a resolution you are happy with.

Comment: @Nij yes, I understood the point you were making and agree with it. I'm already editing the question.

Comment: _"the comments [...] were removed just a few minutes ago. Can the mods see it?"_ Yes, moderators can see deleted comments.

Comment: This is a clear violation of [the Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) (section *"No bigotry."* and *"No harassment."*). Thus there must be a standard way of handling it (though I couldn't immediately find a meta post about this procedure - though that page does have the section *"Reporting"*). Please don't let a clique on a Stack Exchange site prevent this from being handled properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just flag and move on.

Mods see most comment flags. If you want to provide more context it's ok to flag the post this comment thread is on and use a custom flag reason.

Mods can explicitly choose to see deleted comments under a post but deletion of the comment by any means would mark the flags as handled, so the above would be preferred if you think the other user is intentionally self-deleting comments to avoid flags

Comment: By *If you want to provide more context it's ok to flag the post this comment thread is on and use a custom flag reason* you mean the thread where the person was posting?

If that was the case, I did not do it because on the last instance they caused me some annoyance (that was last week I think), I pointed the post and the user and the mods edited it out, so I assumed I should not post it here.

Comment: Yup. So the mods can trivially see the comments involved

Comment: Yeah, I just did it a minute back or so. I may be wrong but I'm foreseeing it getting declined. In the past flags, when the content was okay they declined the flag based on that.

The only abusive comments were the first. Seeing they got removed, they now make sure to have an okay content while still trying to provoke me.

Comment: I mean, the only *explicitly* abusive, like the one where they said I seem to condone rape.

Comment: That's fine. The whole point is to have cooler heads look at the whole situation

Comment: @EzequielBarbosa _"In the past flags, when the content was okay they declined the flag based on that."_ -- And rightfully so (since you said the content was okay). If you don't want to flag the content itself, but rather a user's behavior, or if the flag reason is not obvious, then you should raise a _custom_ mod flag (i.e., "In need of moderator intervention") so you can explain the situation and provide context for moderators as this answer suggests. Otherwise, the mod handling the (regular) flag will not see a valid case for accepting it.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yeah, thanks for the advice. I see where things are going from there.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yeah. Makes sense. Let's see what comes out of it. 

My way of thinking is that there's no way that user can continue with this indefinitely without being called out for it by someone.

Answer (score 7):

In such a case, what I would do is:

1. Flag the user for a cool-down suspension and move on.  Rinse and repeat.
2. If the moderators repeatedly don’t respond to and/or decline valid reports of the same user, then go to the [contact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link (on the site where the offending user resides) and escalate the issue to a CM.  You should also include links to examples of harassment, and a report you made.

That should take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and answering.

I think your answer was very informative, but I chose to handle the situation the way @JourneymanGeek suggested, for the time being.

If that does not solve the issue, I'll try escalating.

Thanks.

Comment: @EzequielBarbosa Cool, glad I could help.