The "talkative" user problem
After asking questions and providing answers here for about 10 years, few days ago I have faced with a very irritating problem.
Currently, the subject of my interest is ImageMagick, a command-line tool for image processing, and the DjVu format. And there appeared a user who began to comment on almost every question I had on these topics on Stack Overflow and Superuser.
The problem is that his comments are totally useless to me. I'm not sure he really understands the technical side (I suppose he does, though not really well), but what I can say for sure is that his sentences are total mess. Words and thoughts are interwinted in the most arbitrary way, missed words, often he doesn't use any  punctuation at all, misspelled words here and there AND ALL CAPS FOR WHATEVER REASON, FOR THE GOD OF CHAOS!!!!!1111 And he is very talkative.
I asked him to make his comments more clear, and he replied that this is simply a bad habit, but then he didn't changed his behavior.
I cannot simply flag his comments as spam or something like this, because, well, at some degree they can be considered useful. But the signal/noise ratio is about 1:20.
His comments is even a more serious problem when there appearing another person in comments who began to reply him. There appearing a nearly-useless, but huge discussion, in which one person posts his "spam" comments, whereas another person is trying to understand what the "talkative" guy is trying to say.
What can I do with this?
Feature request: To provide an option to block certain users to comment on your questions.

The future request is a duplicate of at least: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users  and many more.

I empathise with you, as I have experienced this particular user's noise as well.

That's fine. Comments are transient. If he has something useful to say, it shouldn't be in a comment. Flag as no longer needed. Don't respond (cause they never go away if you feed them). The comments can be pruned or removed as a whole as needed. If there's useful information, it should be in a question or answer.
While I can't speak for Stack Overflow, I'd say on Super User, with our moderator workload, we're good with people flagging things we need to look at. Someone posting semi incoherent comments and annoying people might need a looking at.


To provide an option to block certain users to comment on your questions.

No.
Feel free to flag the user's comments as "No longer needed" or even a custom mod flag if that seems warranted.
The Stack Exchange network is not a social club where you allow/disallow individuals from interacting with you. The question you have posted is for everybody. People can vote/comment/answer/edit it. You do not get to control who touches it as long as they follow the rules.

I do understand Stack Exchange is not Facebook. But please take a note that such comments is not my personal problem: they will be the problem for anyone who visit the question and who want to figure out all the ins and outs from the question itself, answers, and comments.

@jsx97 which just means that it's not a problem with individual user but a problem with content. We have flags for that.


What can I do with this?

Use a browser extension to hide all the activities of a given user on Stack Exchange, e.g. StackIgnore.
