# How do I ignore an individual question?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, questions

Is there a way to ignore individual posts/questions?

So, for example, the top question for "[Highest Voted Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes)" list is always What’s your favorite “programmer” cartoon?

I've seen this post and I no longer wish to see it, can I mark this as "Read"?

I know you can have "ignored tags" but there are lots of C# questions that I'm either not interested in, or don't know enough about to answer and I don't want to ignore all C# questions so setting C# as an ignored tag would hide potentially interesting questions as well.

Comment: Is this the right place to ask this question? Or should I post this on Stack Overflow itself?

Comment: No, this is the right place. Don't post questions *about* stackoverflow *on* stackoverflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide a particular question locally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73719/hide-a-particular-question-locally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently. If you want to view sorted by votes, I highly recommend browsing questions by tag instead.

Just click any tag to get started, then use the "related tags" sidebar to begin combining them.. or do something more advanced

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/

Comment: Answered by Jeff, must be the correct answer :-)

Comment: @jeff - is there any way to get this implemented? it would be **amazing**

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the [Ignore User(s) Script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/greasemonkey-ignore-user-script-now-includes-lists) to ignore questions based upon their id instead...

Comment: This is, logically, exactly what I'd like, however I do wonder what the script performance would be like once there were thousands of article IDs