# Is there a way to ignore a specific question?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I ignore an individual question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/how-do-i-ignore-an-individual-question)

I keep seeing [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469899/whats-the-worst-security-hole-youve-ever-seen) make the front page for the last few days. I don't want to ignore the tag, but I would like to ignore that question. Anything I can do?

Comment: I'd rather you put the tick on "random" - his comment, after all.

Comment: @Marc You put "quotes" there like it's a dirty "word."

Comment: It occurs to me that actively changing a setting to ignore something is the _opposite_ of really ignoring it.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn - I don't agree. Have you ever used IRC or been in trade chat on WoW? Two places where /ignore is invaluable at times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your view and forget about looking at the front page.

- Click Questions
- Click Newest tab

No problem any more as the floating question gets pushed further back every day. If you want to view Active, then that's just how the bubble bobbles.

Taking a look at the actual question in question, [What's the worst security hole you've ever seen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469899/whats-the-worst-security-hole-youve-ever-seen) it's apparently the only question making use of the [`[security-hole]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/security-hole) tag.

You should be good to ignore that specific tag and not have it invade your eyeball space in future.

Comment: Maybe edit your comment into this too?

Comment: Always time for rep-whoring on Meta.

Comment: Re "random" quotes - that is mainly to distinguish them from random quotes, whi"ch ar"e "li"ke th"is. Or picking an answer at random.

Answer (score 3):

Which question, and what is causing it to bump? If it is being inappropriately edited (etc) we can lock it. Other than that, I find "not looking at it" works fairly well for me...

But if there is a problem on this question, let us know. Flagging for moderator on the site would work, or raising it here...

There may also be a grease-monkey script somewhere; there usually is...

Comment: I don't think is in approiate, just popular and I don't care about the subject. For the record its here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469899/whats-the-worst-security-hole-youve-ever-seen

Comment: @jrob You don't want to just ignore the `security-hole` tag? It's the only question using it right now.

Comment: security-hole works, i was thinking more of subjective. Thanks!

Comment: I'm included to fully agree with random's comment...

Comment: Still need "Belongs on TDWTF" close reason...

Comment: @Shog: there wouldn't be enough space for the index...

Comment: Hey: 10K club FTW!

Comment: Also: whenever I come across a question using tag that is exclusive to that question, I almost always remove the tag. I wouldn't count on 'security-hole' staying with the question forever... (that said, I'll leave this one alone just for you. If it disappears, I didn't do it).

Comment: If it sticks with it long enough for the discussion to die down, i am happy. :)