# Does Markdown have a way to express strikeout?

Tags: support, markdown

I've been using `<s>` to put <s>strikeout</s> in posts -- is there a Markdown way of doing it?

It seems like `-[Text here]` would make sense, hehe :)

Comment: Some markdown engines use `~text~` for strike through, but this doesn't work in stackoverflow.

Comment: Pandoc uses `~~strike this~~`. So does Github, Bitbucket, …

Answer (score 114, accepted):

**<s>Yes.</s>         No.         <s>Maybe so.</s>**

This means that **[comments may not include strikeouts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31228/comments-should-support-the-strike-element)**.

Comment: So in other words, the answer is no, there is no markdown way of expressing it. :*(

Comment: I <s>love</s> hate StackExchange comments :P (And their lack of ability for me to use strikeout)

Comment: @svnpenn - "Happiness and the absurd are two sons of the same earth. They are inseparable." _Albert Camus_

Comment: Where in this answer you wrote how to type a strikeout?????!?!!!??!?!?!

Comment: @Ahmad The answer allows you to use `html` tags like <s> (which stands for strike-through). But they don't work in comments.

Comment: @Ahmad, you can always click the "edit" button (or the "improve this question/answer" button, even if you're not logged in) to see how a post's formatting was typed in.

Comment: Not everybody knows about the tiny edit button. People might not have enough reputation to edit it also. I have edited the answer to show <s> tags

Comment: T̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶m̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶d̶ ̶o̶u̶t̶  [using this](http://yaytext.com/strike/)

Comment: @pulsejet It's just a broken underline that is a tad to high, typographically.

Answer (score 66):

`<del>` also works. <del>As you can see here.</del> It might be more semantically correct, especially if you include the "datetime" attribute.

Comment: It *might* be more semantically correct. I often use strikeout to denote done items, so in that case the semantic is different than "deleted". But you are right, in some case `<del>` is semantically more accurate.

Comment: Came here through a google search, `<del>` sounds nice, esp. with a datetime attribute, but it also removed code formatting whereas `<s>` did not.

Comment: Except `<del>` isn't Markdown; it would be HTML, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Sarah: Of course it's HTML. The answer to "Does markdown have a way to express strikeout?" is "No, but you can use some HTML to accomplish the same thing on Stack Exchange sites. Here's how..."

Comment: @AlE.: Okay, sorry about that. My mistake. I thought the question had to do with Markdown, specifically, not just Markdown on Stack Exchange. Because some sites and Markdown editors do not support HTML, just Markdown. So I was just stating. Thanks for clarifying on that. :)

Comment: @Sarah: A question about Markdown in general would be off-topic here. This site is for questions about the workings of the Stack Exchange network and the software that empowers it, thus by definition the question would have to be about the Stack Exchange flavor of Markdown.

Comment: @ale With `datetime` attribute it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 49):

It's rather inconsistent.  In regular questions/answers, you can use `<s>HTML tags</s>` to get strikethrough text <s>like this</s>:

```
<s>like this</s>
```

In chat, you can surround text with `---` to get strikethrough, but this doesn't work in regular questions/answers:

```
---strikethrough text---
```

Comment: And it looks like <s>neither method</s> works in comments to ---achieve--- strikethrough.

Comment: U̶s̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶c̶e̶ ̶L̶u̶k̶e̶ ̶:̶)̶

Comment: @Noctis y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶h̶e̶a̶t̶e̶d̶!̶  +1 for [lateral](http://adamvarga.com/strike/) thinking, _UTF8 the force Luke_ 

Comment: @earcam it's only cheating if you break the rules ... The first rule of f̶i̶g̶h̶t̶c̶l̶u̶b̶ is that you don't speak about f̶i̶g̶h̶t̶c̶l̶u̶b̶ ... :)

Answer (score 32):

It **may** be off-topic, but since I came to this question while looking for a contextualized solution on [Bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.org) and GitHub, I'd like to add the `double tilde` too, the only which worked in real [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

~~example~~

Comment: since you mention Bitbucket I thought I'd add I just found you can use hypens around a phrase in Jira to get strikethrough, eg `-deleted-`

Comment: The double tilde is excellent, because it also works in **Trello**.

Comment: This works while entering the markdown @ PR comments in bitbucket

Comment: ~~Test~~ (one day, maybe)

Answer (score 11):

Though a strike-through syntax wasn't available in the original Markdown, as of today (2015), many implementations have unofficially settled on the <kbd>~</kbd>(tilde) character which is supported on [Reddit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit) and as someone here mentioned, on [Bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket) too.

Let's hope Stack Overflow also adds this syntax to its Markdown implementation soon!

Comment: It's unlikely, since `~` is not used for strike-through in the [current CommonMark spec](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.22/), which SE will be moving to once it stabilizes a bit more.

Comment: (Skype has also introduced `~` for formatting strikethrough.)

Answer (score 5):

Why is the selected answer such a wrong and imprecise one?! 
Well, probably because people answer in comments rather than in... an answer.

Anyway. 
While **Markdown technically doesn't support strikethrough at the moment**, several comments pointed out that **using strikethrough in comments *is* possible**. \
It is not handy, since `~` isn't supported yet, but actually possible (using Unicode characters)

So, to strike through text **in questions, use the  or  tags** \
*Example <s>striked</s> out using  tag* \
*Example <del>striked</del> out using  tag*

**For comments, use external converters or tools**, like those websites (credits go to respective commenters) \
http://yaytext.com/strike/ \
E̶x̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶d̶ ̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶y̶a̶y̶t̶e̶x̶t̶ (long strikethrough)  
http://adamvarga.com/strike/ \
E̶x̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶d̶ ̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶d̶a̶m̶v̶a̶r̶g̶a̶ (note the site also features an extension.  I did install a similar one for Gmail, once: that may be very handy.)

Comment: And for the sake of completeness : `E̵̵̵x̵̵̵a̵̵̵m̵̵̵p̵̵̵l̵̵̵e̵̵̵ ̵̵̵s̵̵̵t̵̵̵r̵̵̵i̵̵̵k̵̵̵e̵̵̵d̵̵̵ ̵̵̵o̵̵̵u̵̵̵t̵̵̵ ̵̵̵u̵̵̵s̵̵̵i̵̵̵n̵̵̵g̵̵̵ ̵̵̵y̵̵̵a̵̵̵y̵̵̵t̵̵̵e̵̵̵x̵̵̵t̵̵̵ ̵(̵s̵h̵o̵r̵t̵ ̵s̵t̵r̵i̵k̵e̵t̵h̵r̵o̵u̵g̵h̵)̵ (̶l̶o̶n̶g̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶)̶ (̴t̴i̴l̴d̴e̴ ̴s̴t̴r̴i̴k̴e̴t̴h̴r̴o̴u̴g̴h̴)̴` E̶x̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶d̶ ̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶d̶a̶m̶v̶a̶r̶g̶a̶ 
Looks like some work better than other :p

Comment: That's not part of markdown, just special characters, hence not a direct answer to the question here which clearly asks for a way using markdown.

Comment: Indeed, my bad.  Guess I should move my answer to one of the other more relevant questions, like "Is strikethrough allowed in comments".  Meh, my tabs are closed now...
Looks like I let myself troll by the answer, which states "comment may not include strikeout" while thats not what the question was asking for.  Still... looks like this means the selected answer remains a bad one, right ?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135209/is-there-a-way-to-strike-out-text-in-comments.

Comment: After a 2nd glance at this, the reason I answered here was clearly the selected answer.  It affirms _"comments may not include strikeouts"_, which is **wrong**, and shows stroke-out text without even explaining how to do it.
I visited a few other threads, including the one you link here, and they fortunately got more useful answers, which is why I answered _here_.

So I just edited my answer to precise that "While markdown technically doesn't provide strikethrough ATM, you may achieve it with unicode"