# Can we add strikeout to markdown sharp (and by extension the stack exchange sites)?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown

This question is more in response to the answer to [my previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63768/does-markdown-have-a-way-to-express-strikeout)

Seems like `-[this is strikeout]` would reasonably result in <s>this is strikeout</s> -- given that `![alt]` is already used for images.

That way you could [use strikeout in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31228/comments-should-support-the-strike-element).

Comment: It should be noted that being in markdown does not guarantee allowance in comments - comments only support a limitted form of markdown. To use your very own case, this isn't going to render as an image: ![♪](http://imgur.com/3XBHj.png).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why? Strikeout is already supported in the HTML, eg,

`<s>not this again</s>`

produces

<s>not this again</s>

(yes, `<strike>` also works)

I don't see any real value in adding random new Markdown syntax when the HTML we all know and love works fine.

Comment: Good choice. To extend a bit on this: "adding random new Markdown syntax" implies that basic Markdown itself does not support the proposed syntax (while it [does support](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img) the image syntax that was mentioned in the question). Making up a new syntax for strikethrough would probably not make a lot of people use it (many simply being oblivious about its existence), but meanwhile make it hard for third-parties to interpret the data dumps.

Comment: Except it *doesn't* work in a comment. <strike>Example</strike> <s>Example</s>.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a fan of Trello solution: they use double tilde for strikeout text `~~like this~~`, that appears rendered <del>like this</del> (they use the `<del>` HTML tag).

It's easy to remember, and resembles the `**` we are already using for **boldly emphasized** text.