# Strikethrough without space is not working in chat

Tags: bug, chat, markdown

Intra-word strikethrough in chat is not working. [This](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/60231487/history) does not render as having a strikethrough:

> T---e---st

Is this by-design or not?

Comment: Related: [Does Markdown have a way to express strikeout?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63768/does-markdown-have-a-way-to-express-strikeout)