# Please include info about spoiler sections on the "formatting help" page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, spoilers, help-text

As described on [Add markdown support for hidden-until-you-click text (aka spoilers)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396), it's now possible to create spoiler blocks/hidden text with the syntax

```
>! Spoiler text
```

Can a blurb about this be added to the "formatting help" page that's linked to in the "How to format" box on the right of posting pages and by the little ? block above post entry fields?

[image: screenshot of the formatting help links]

Comment: For the time being, it's documented on [SO-specific markup - definitive resource?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74999/so-specific-markup-definitive-resource/79591#79591), which is not easy to find.

Comment: @badp which site(s) other than Gaming use the spoiler text feature?

Comment: How about [Meta SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81729/markdown-parsing-might-have-some-infinite-loop-for-some-malformed-long-pattern/81747#81747)? :)

Comment: why isn't this tagged [meta-tag:status-completed]? http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers

Comment: @gnat fixed now.