# Markdown parsing might have some infinite loop for some malformed long pattern

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

Markdown parsing might have some infinite loop for some malformed long pattern

Try copy paste following line or two to any markdown enable box

```
>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!<!
>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!>!<!
```

Preview UI hang in my browser (firefox, chrome, opera) became CPU usage 99% and

When I disable preview javascript and send POST request to server, server also does not response the request for long time, and sometimes got gateway timeout error and sometimes, my account logoff automatically :D)

May be not a serious issue, but may be worth a look.

Comment: Reproing this on my machine was a **bad idea**...

Comment: If it loops the server it may be a very serious issue since it can allow ddos attacks

Comment: deleting for now since this is a DDOS repro

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, great catch -- now fixed. Was an error in the spoiler block post-processor

> OMG spoilers!

```
> ! OMG spoilers!
```

Comment: FYI: the [live preview](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396) while editing currently does not work (not with `>!`, nor with `> !`).

Comment: @arjan you sure about that? :)

Comment: I take the smiley means you've fixed it? Good! (I noticed as I wondered if the syntax had changed from `>!` into `> !` with a space. While testing, none worked, until I indeed saved. Then both worked. Never knew about that space!)