# Please update the editing help

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, markdown, editing-help

I only recently learned about [a new feature to insert those fancy tags into your post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482).

I didn't know what the exact syntax was. It was only now that I needed it myself, and I've been searching like a crazy for it before I found that specific post here on meta.

It would be nice if this was reflected in the [editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

And while we're at it, maybe also include [this recently added feature (the ability to specify the language of your code blocks)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971).

Comment: [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74999/so-specific-markup-definitive-resource/79591#79591) also have a list of updates to add to the editing help, including the Spoilers markup.

Comment: It would be nice is someone step on and, at least, tag it status-declined, status-required or status-deferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those feature (and a few more) have been added to the Markdown help page (available after the next build). This is site-specific in some cases, so e.g. the Stack Overflow version doesn't include LaTeX, and the english.SE version doesn't mention syntax highlighting.

We're looking at more improvements to that page*, but at least this information is now included.

<sub>* Here are 20 billion different ways to write a link, ordered by awesomeness! Scroll down 2.5 miles if you want to know how to create a spoiler.</sub>