# How to colorize code in SO code block?

Tags: support, code-formatting

I suppose this question has been asked here at least ten times, but it seems my searches have not been successfull so far.

But anyways, how to you put that fancy code coloring inside the <pre></pre> or <code></code> tags in a StackOverflow question? I tried the <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> but it just indents the statement.

Comment: Indented lines show up as Highlighted code, you should see that in the preview : )

Comment: The [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) should really be updated... see also [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82329/please-update-the-editing-help).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: @Arjan, he's trying to get the Color in the codeblock, and not a code-block itself.

Comment: True, @fireDude67, but coloring is part of the formatting, and the answer is in that FAQ.

Answer (score 9):

You can choose the language per code block, and it will get proper colors.

For example, C# code block:

```
Example e = new Example();
```

Some HTML:

```
<div><p>hello!</p></div>
```

How to do this? Add such line above the code block, with one blank line between them:
`<!-- language: lang-cs -->`
This is for `C#`, it can be `html`, `js` and more.

For more details: [Syntax highlighting: what about answering with a different language than the one used in the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79785/syntax-highlighting-what-about-answering-with-a-different-language-than-the-one/81973#81973)

Without specifying the language yourself, the language will be taken from the question tags.

Answer (score 1):

The coloring is by-default for code indented with 4 or more spaces.

For more information refer [Code and Preformatted Text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Here is an example

```
Example e = new Example();
```

Comment: Wow, the colors are stunning `:-)` (Ah, you posted this _before_ the migration.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is for [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), but the code gets formatted automatically:

```
public class Test {
   public string MyString { get; set }
}
```

Just indent the code with 4 spaces and you're off into code mode.