# Problem with Code Formatting

Tags: support, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Manually specify language for syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting)

For some reason when I edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556667/valueinjecter-recursive-mapping), and I select the relevant code portions, and hit the code formatting button, my code becomes formatted and colored.  When I save my edits, however, the coloring goes away.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Chris, it seems as though it's not working since my question doesn't have any language tags; it's not supposed to.  Is there a way to manually tell the code formatter which language to use?

Comment: You don't have any language tags on the post. You can tell it what to use, but I can't remember the syntax.

Comment: See - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79785/syntax-highlighting-what-about-answering-with-a-different-language-than-the-one/81973#81973

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there is other way to [tell the code formatter which language to use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971), but the [help should be updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82329/please-update-the-editing-help)