# Why is there no syntax highlighting in this answer?

Tags: support, specific-question, syntax-highlighting

Hello, I'm trying to understand why syntax-highlighting isn't working on one of [my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630899/hello-world-bootloader-not-working/2631434#2631434).

At first, I didn't have any lang-tag. This resulted in no syntax highlighting. Then, I added the lang-tag of `lang-default`, which I assumed would restore SO's sane default highlighting style. It worked in the preview, but actually on the page you can see there is no syntax highlighting to be found. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Language hinting must be done directly before each and every code block to which it is to apply.

Comment: Well, even then, can we get some kind of default language hinting for the assembly tag?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like "assembly" language doesn't seem to be supported by google code prettify:

http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html

Comment: Yes, but the default highlighter works decently

Comment: @Earlz, you mean like this? - http://i.imgur.com/9qwwA.png

Comment: yes, it requires a bit of hacking to work around comments, but I think it looks better than plain formatting