# Include explicit Google Prettify instructions in the markdown help

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting, editing-help

If I understand it correctly, SO is supporting Google Prettify.  There is no information about this within the Markdown editing notes (the Code section of the toolbar and in the advanced help).

I think it would be a good idea to add this information, as the link to the Prettify docs doesn't exactly give the details I'd like.  For example, an explicit example of how to specify a language (for example, it is unclear if the Prettify comment must be indented or not) and what languages/tags are supported.

Comment: Ehhh, it's automagic in most cases because it does it based on the tags.  It's only really necessary in rare cases where the tags don't match up with the actual source being formatted or there are multiple languages in use.  If you showed a mockup of how you intended to link it, I may vote up but otherwise I don't know that it's worth the extra confusion.

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo: But when it is *not* automagic, it might be nice to know *exactly* how it works.  I can easily prove why this would be nice... I tried doing it and couldn't figure out how.  And I'm a super brainiac smartypants.

Comment: In the meantime, there's a community (ahem)-maintained [markdown help complement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74999/so-specific-markup-definitive-resource/79591#79591). Please contribute if you see anything wrong or missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, great idea, is there now:

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

You have good suggestions. Well, most of the time. :)

Comment: All of the time.  All.  Of.  The.  Time.  Oh, that reminds me.  There are some pluralization issues I've been meaning to add bug reports for.

Comment: That's syntax from HTML or something but not from Markdown, which makes writing less interesting.