# Add "---text---" to chat FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, markdown

It's possible to <s>strike</s> a line in chat by surrounding it with triple dashes:

```
---Struck out text---
```

However, that's not specified in **[the chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting)**. I think it should be added.

Comment: Oddly your first --- was left alone while your second --- got converted to an em dash.

Comment: @BenBrocka: I did notice that. Peculiar.

Comment: @BenBrocka The regex is `---?(\s)`, so the first one doesn't match. Not sure why space is required on one end but not the other, though.

Comment: When balpha introduced this feature, he said (in chat) that it was experimental and could be taken away at any time. I don't have a link available at the moment, though.

Comment: Update to previous comment: [found it](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/548485#548485). "This is just experimental -- I make no guarantee that I won't turn it off again soon." That was 14 months ago, so I guess it does deserve to be considered for the FAQ.

Comment: What's 14 months in the grand scheme of things? :) But yeah, I guess we could add it now. /cc @pop

Comment: +1 Just tonight I was trying to find out how to do this, but couldn't find it anywhere!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I've added it to the "How do I format my message" section (which also appears when you click "help" in the chat room).