# A way to ignore specific questions

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide a particular question locally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73719/hide-a-particular-question-locally)

I would really like a private-to-me tag, like Favorite, but kinda the opposite -- something that lets me ignore specific posts and by ignore, I mean 'exclude from lists'. I like to look at the unanswered list for certain tags, looking for things I know about or can help with. Some questions on the unanswered lists seem to languish for some time, and hinder ready access to questions further down the lists, that I might know something about. As for the questions I want to ignore: I don't know anything that would help, and I'm not interested, so I want to not see that question again in these lists. It would be ideal if it they would still show up in search results (if they match), just not in the unanswered, highest voted, and featured lists. (It's less of an issue for the newest and active lists.)

I don't want a public tag, since this is just about me specifically. I don't want to ignore the user as a whole, it's just this question. I don't (usually) want to ignore whole tags. I just want some way to take these specific posts out of my view of the lists, to clear the way to questions I might know something about.

Comment: Oh yeah. Totally. Someone with the power, please close as dupe of that.