# Top unanswered question on CSS tag is from 6/2012

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, unanswered-questions

When you go to [css](/questions/tagged/css), click the "Unanswered" tab. The top question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256476/flickering-issue-while-navigating-between-pages-using-multipage-template-in-jque), which is from June 29, 2012. There are other questions that are less than a week old, and most all are from the past 3 months.

But a question asked so long ago as 2012-06-29 is probably a) useless to the OP, and/or b) unlikely to be answered now, and/or c) out-of-date. Should a question of this age either a) be deleted, or b) removed from the top list?

Comment: A similar case on [tag:php], where [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753584/flow3-action-parameters-and-arrays-of-objects) was asked 2011-10-13. It was last edited on 2012-11-29.

Comment: Despite my answer, I do understand it can be annoying to see the same questions all the time, but hiding a question from everyone is not really the right approach.  There are [feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7603/the-ability-to-hide-questions) [requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73719/hide-a-particular-question-locally) to allow you to hide specific questions so you don't have to seem them anymore.  Show your support for them.  And there are solutions in the answers to both questions that allow you to do that now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why should we do anything about it?  Is the question actively harmful?

But to address your specific concerns:

> But a question asked so long ago as 2012-06-29 is probably a) useless to the OP,

Why should the usefulness to the OP matter?  If we judged on that, we'd have to delete all questions once the OP got their answer.  Granted, the OP is to have likely not going to need a solution after this time, but what about someone else?

> b) unlikely to be answered now

One way we frequent suggest new users get rep is to find old unanswered questions and try to find the solution.  This is a good question for them to try to solve.  And there are also badges ([Revival](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/837/revival) and [Necromancer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer)) for being the first to answer an old question.

> c) out-of-date.

There are still useful questions from 2008, so why is one that is barely a year old going to not be useful?  Also, 6 people upvoted it (so they must have thought it a good question) and according to the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11256476/timeline), all of the upvotes have occurred in the last 5 months, so I'd think it was still relevant.