# Create a blacklist to keep from seeing certain users

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Not everyone abides by the rules of Stack Overflow. Sometimes they abuse the system by insulting other users as well as down-voting their questions, among other things. It would be nice if a user could have blacklist, perhaps enabling read-only access to that group of users.

This would not only help the victims of those users, but also Moderators, who constantly have to intervene to resolve petty conflicts, becoming a bigger problem as the community expands.

Comment: **Duplicate of:** http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users , **Solution:** http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script

Comment: Not exact duplicates, but leading to the same idea. Being able to shield yourself from down-votes is also against the entire system. Ignore users if you don't want to see what they're saying, but they have every right to express their opinions on your posts.