# Can I block annoying or hostile users?

Tags: support, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a blacklist to keep from seeing certain users.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5879/create-a-blacklist-to-keep-from-seeing-certain-users)

One user in particular is being very aggressive, negative, and simply wrong. Can I block this user from my question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should definitely flag the problem posts for moderator attention with an explanation, since we don't tolerate hostile behavior.

See related discussion and user script:

[Ignore Users Script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script)

(browse the "linked" sidebar on that page for the discussion)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this. However, you could write a user script that hides answers and comments from those users.

If someone is aggressive, flag or discuss him/her on meta. And don't forget any nessecary downvotes!

Comment: I'd like to be able to remind myself if a given user has a tendency to delete their questions after you've invested time in providing a good answer. Some habitual offenders and would rather not waste my time again in the future... pet peeve.

Comment: How do you write a user script that hides answers and comments from those users? I'm being bullied by a user with a high rep score, and what appears to be his sock puppets or some kind of alliance with friends on wordpress.stackexchange.com. My rep score there is too low to do anything about it. I fear that he is moderating my flagging, so what recourse do I have?