# Can we have a User Black List?

Tags: feature-request, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a blacklist to keep from seeing certain users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5879/create-a-blacklist-to-keep-from-seeing-certain-users)

At the risk of losing many rep points, I'd like to suggest that we have a list of users whose questions we prefer not to answer. Usually, when I read a question, I do not look at who asked it. I decide to answer based on the question and existing answers.

Frustratingly, sometimes I encounter users who don't want to do any work themselves. I'll answer their question, and then they ping me with comment after comment along the lines of "but how do I do ...". In the end, they aren't happy until someone writes the entire project for them. Usually this takes them about 4 questions in fairly quick succession.

Don't get me wrong, I'm happy to help folks out, and I'll answer a newbie's question or 0%-accepted-answer user's question with no qualms. But these folks who refuse to do any work on their own bug me, and I'd rather not answer their questions, at least for a while.

It would be great if I could have a list of users like this. Then, every time I encounter a frustrating situation that prompts SO to suggest I move to Chat, I can add that person to my blacklist and not get suckered again. Even if the additions expire after, say, a week, that would still be nice.

For those who disagree, I'd really love to read what you do about these sorts of encounters.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29840/add-a-mechanism-to-warn-me-when-i-start-to-answer-a-question-for-a-user-with-whom, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users

Comment: I really don't think it's in the spirit of the site. Besides, that's what bad reputation is for, right?

Comment: Duplicate of this (deleted) question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21122/twit-filter-for-stackoverflow

Comment: This userscript might do what you want: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script

Answer (score -3):

**I do not agree with this**

Who is creating this list?

Who on the stack exchange has enough non-bias opinions to create such a list?

It could be one day a user has a few questions in quick succession that garner answer, but then another day he or she answer a bunch of questions for other users in the same topic?

Who are we to question an OP's integrity?

Comment: It's a personal list for my use only. Each user has his/her own list, invisible to all others.